# Reservoir Dogs: "Let's go to work" in Latin

Tags: idiom, sentence-translation, motto

I'm a programmer and I regularly write small utility programs for friends and family. Since I like a joke, all those programs have help/about forms that describe the program as having been produced by a completely fictional company. So far so boring. However, I would like my "company" to have a motto* in Latin and the motto I have chosen is "Let's go to work" but specifically in the sense Joe Cabot uses in Reservoir Dogs — [short clip here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiCxMnG8OfTAhUHilQKHWmrANgQtwIIPDAH&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dailymotion.com%2Fvideo%2Fx4cbs5u_let-s-go-to-work-reservoir-dogs_shortfilms&usg=AFQjCNHs1Xu67fQagAASoBMXYXfeNogZtg&sig2=1x9s36FiYrLl9uAS1BBFHg]).

Refining my searches a bit (my Google-fu must be weak), I keep coming up with "et eamus ad operandum", so I suppose my question is really: is "et eamus ad operandum" valid, and does it actually mean "let's go to work"?

Many thanks to @Rafael and @Joonas Ilmavirta for the guidance and for keeping me plugging away.

*Motto might not even be the right word, but you know what I mean.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. For your question to be on-topic, you need to show an effort to translate it yourself (preferably more than just Google Translate, usually not very good) and ask for corrections/suggestions. Many of us are eager to help!

Comment: Hi @Rafael - I have tried searching Google (not Translate, which I have read on here is pretty much no use whatsoever) but have found zero answers; I have no Latin myself so I'm a bit adrift here. If I am off-topic (for which I apologize), please just have a mod close the question; I admit it is a bit of an odd one. I can edit in my last couple of searches if that will help.

Comment: Give [this](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) a try before you give up ;)

Comment: @Spratty Welcome to the site! It's perfectly fine if you don't know any Latin, and I can blame no one for [steering clear of Google Translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), but I do suggest editing in what you could figure out yourself, no matter how little it is. Looking at [any of the many online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) (Rafael linked to one) might help you find the kind of word for "work" you want. I will put this on hold now, but I will immediately reopen once you edit to add details. (The closure reason is not descriptive.)

Comment: [This clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pX9c-k53ksA) might provide more context for the precise nuance of "Let's go to work."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. "Let's ..." is formed using the present active subjunctive first person plural form.
2. Your sentence can be rendered as "let's work" or "let's go to [a figurative place called] work".
3. There are two ways to write Latin: with macron or without macron. (Obviously there are other ways, such as with apices, with breves, etc.) Macrons are used in a more academical context, so you may want the version without macrons.
4. There are three ways to speak Latin: the reconstructed classical way (weni, widi, wiki), the ecclesiastical way (veni, vidi, vici), the English way (veenai, vidai, vichai). You may want the English way.
5. In the Classical pronunciations,`ː` signifies a long vowel.

### Let's work

#### First translation

- With macron: Labōrēmus.
- Without macron: Laboremus.
- Classical: `la.boː.REː.mus`
- Ecclesiastical: `la.bo.RE.mus`
- English: `luh-bow-REE-muhs`

#### Second translation

- With macron: Operēmur.
- Without macron: Operemur.
- Classical: `o.pe.REː.mur`
- Ecclesiastical: `o.pe.RE.mur`
- English: `oh-puh-RE-mer`

### Let's go to work

- With macron: Ad labōrem eāmus.
- Without macron: Ad laborem eamus.
- Classical: `ad.la.BOː.re.me.Aː.mus`
- Ecclesiastical: `ad.la.BO.rem.e.A.mus`
- English: `ad-luh-BOW-ruhm-ee-EI-muhs`

Note that "ad labōrem" can be switched with "eāmus".

Comment: "Ad laborem eamus" it is then - thank you for your help, @Leaky Nun - super code-golfer _and_ Latin expert :-)

Comment: @Spratty Far from an expert.