# Translating "do the next thing" to Latin

Tags: translation-check, motto, english-to-latin-translation

I would like to use the phrase "do the next thing" as a *motto* for some literature. Does the translation *FACITE DEINDE REM* work? 
The thought is basically this: we should get active with the next thing that's in front of us without too much concern for anything else.

The phrase comes from a poem:

> From an old English parsonage down by the sea There came in the twilight a message to me; Its quaint Saxon legend, deeply engraven, Hath, it seems to me, teaching from Heaven. And on through the doors the quiet words ring Like a low inspiration: “DO THE NEXT THING.” Do it immediately, do it with prayer; Do it reliantly, casting all care; Do it with reverence, tracing His hand Who placed it before thee with earnest command. Stayed on Omnipotence, safe ‘neath His wing, Leave all results, do the next thing.

Comment: Fac rem quó sequitur, can work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "famous" phrase out there that might represents a similar concept to the one you are interested on: "[*carpe diem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpe_diem)", which is normally understood to mean "seize the day". You could also build related phrases like *carpe momentum* (seize the moment), or *carpe vitam* (seize life).

Regarding your suggested expression, <s>as far as I can see, it is grammatically correct.</s> as Rafael's comment noted, *[deinde](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deinde)* is an adverb, and thus would be directly related to the verb *carpe* and not of the noun *res*.

Another option could be *facite sequens rem*, or *facite sequentem rem*. The L&S dictionary gives the meaning "next, following, subsequent" to *[sequens](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=sequens)*, particularly in a temporal meaning. This is a participle which can be directly related to a noun (e.g. in English, "broken" in "the broken window"). Thus, in this case *facite sequens rem* would be "do the following thing".

---

Update: Based on the context just added to the question, the singular of *facite* ([*fac*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/facio#Conjugation)) might be more relevant here, as it seems the message was destined to one person. Thus, my suggestion would be *fac sequens rem*, or *fac sequentem rem*.

Answer (score 2):

If it is an order, directed to a single person, an alternative could be:

> rem proximam fac

But I'm not quite convinced.

- The problem with *deinde* is that it is an adverb, and as such, it needs to modify a verb. To modify *rem* (a noun) you need an adjective. Proxima means both *nearest* and *next* (in feminine). I like this ambiguity in the *careless* context you want to give to the sentence. *Proxima* has been [translated as next](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0019%3Atext%3DTul.%3Achapter%3D9&highlight=next), e.g. in ([Cic. Tul. 9](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0015:text=Tul.:chapter=9&highlight=proxima)):

  > *Proxima nocte, iam fere cum lux adpropinquaret...* The next night, when it was near day-break...

  An alternative for *next* is [Sequens](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dsequens). It also means *the next* at least in a sequence in time. *Disclosure: I'm not sure either is the best adjective for next, but are fit ones anyway. I think proxima is better*.
- Facite is plural, as in the order directed to two or more people. *Proximam rem facite* or *facite rem proximam* are valid. (Word order in Latin is pretty free: the -m in rem means that's the thing being done; putting the object before the verb adds emphasis on the former).
- If it is more like "let's do the next thing" you could say **rem proximam *faciamus***. You have to choose one verbal form. Unfortunately Latin does not offer that exquisite ambiguity English has, that allows to convey so many meanings at a time.
- Another verb for *to do* in this context could be *ago*, hence *age/agite sequentem rem* or *rem sequentem age/agite*. They are different and which one to use could depend on what kind of thing is to be done. There is not an exact mapping with English verbs *to do* and *to make*.

---

Now, I'm not sure how idiomatic it is in Latin to apply the verb *facio* (as in fac, or even *ago*) to a *thing* (as in rem). But if you want to reproduce the vagueness of *do the thing*, I can't think of a better option.

If your Latin motto can be more precise in order to be idiomatic, *to complete a task*/*perform a duty* is well said with the verb *conficio*.

It is also common to replace [adjective] + *thing*, by the sole adjective in its neuter gender form: *bonum*-good thing, *mala*-bad things, etc. Generalizing this rule you could say *proximum*-next/nearest thing. I'm not sure this is *fully* idiomatic either, but sounds good to me. So depending on the addressee, you have these three alternatives:

> **proximum confice** (you, one person)
>   **proximum conficite** (you, two or more people)
>   **proximum conficiamus** (we)

The first one (*proximum confice*) could arguably be read with ambiguity, since proximum could also be the subject (it would make a very weird sentence though, so I wouldn't worry about that).

---

A bunch of additional ideas:

- Alternative (though more specific) words for *thing*: Duty might be *pensum*. Some words for task that come to my mind are: *opus* (n., meaning work as in work of art), or the related *opera* (f.) and *operatio* (f.), *negotium* (n., occupation), and even labor (although it's more closely related to suffering).
- Looking at the sense you want to give, perhaps something in the line of *[let's go to work](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4357/reservoir-dogs-lets-go-to-work-in-latin)* can do the trick too.

Comment: I might say "ad proximum!", ie "[On] to the next thing!"