# Are these short translations correct?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

Hello you wonderful people,

Could you please help me checking if these sentences mean what I think?

Memento vitae - Remember Life

Memento amorem - Remember Love

Memento aeternitas - Remember Eternity

Its for a gift for my wife and it will be engraved in a pendant, so any help is welcome

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site! It seems that you created two accounts. I recommend [following these instructions to merge them](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you get full access to your own question. That includes getting privileges from any votes you get, the ability to accept the best answer, the ability to respond to comments, and alerts of any answers you get.

Answer (score 8):

*Memini* can take either [an accusative or a genitive](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4466/what-is-the-difference-between-accusative-and-genitive-with-meminisse), and there is a difference in meaning, but you're presumably modelling this on *"memento mori"*, so let's use an accusative (*mori* may not particularly look like an accusative but it's an infinitive and infinitives are neuter so the nominative and accusative are identical). *Memento* is obviously fine: it's a 2nd person singular imperative.

*Vita* is the correct word to use for *life*, but its accusative is *vitam* (*vitae* actually is the genitive, so a point to machine translation for once): **memento vitam**

*Amorem* is indeed the accusative of *amor*, meaning *love*: **memento amorem**

*Aeternitas* does mean *eternity*, but its accusative is *aeternitatem*: **memento aeternitatem**