# What does the "Lorem Ipsum" mean?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, origin

"Lorem ipsum" is a filler text commonly used to demonstrate the graphic elements of a document or visual presentation. But what does it mean? Can you give a brief review of the text's origin?

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.

Full text on [loremipsum.nl](http://loremipsum.nl/).

Answer (score 12):

The text is not a coherent passage of Latin but rather is derived from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. [This website](http://nl.lipsum.com/) has both sections and their English translations:

> Sectie 1.10.32 van "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", geschreven door
>   Cicero in 45 v.Chr.
>
> "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
>   accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae
>   ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta
>   sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit
>   aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos
>   qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui
>   dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed
>   quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam
>   aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum
>   exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex
>   ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in
>   ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum
>   qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
>
> 1914 vertaling door H. Rackham
>
> "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing
>   pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete
>   account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great
>   explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one
>   rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure,
>   but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally
>   encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there
>   anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself,
>   because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in
>   which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a
>   trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical
>   exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any
>   right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that
>   has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces
>   no resultant pleasure?"
>
> Sectie 1.10.33 van "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", geschreven door
>   Cicero in 45 v.Chr.
>
> "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui
>   blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores
>   et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident,
>   similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est
>   laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita
>   distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio
>   cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus,
>   omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus
>   autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe
>   eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae.
>   Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
>   voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus
>   asperiores repellat."
>
> 1914 vertaling door H. Rackham
>
> "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike
>   men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of
>   the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain
>   and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those
>   who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as
>   saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly
>   simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of
>   choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do
>   what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain
>   avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty
>   or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures
>   have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore
>   always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he
>   rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he
>   endures pains to avoid worse pains."

Comment: I think there's more to this than that it was "derived" from this passage.

Comment: I believe the prevailing theory is that some printer back in the 1500s who wanted to produce a type specimen book took existing page galleys and scrambled them a bit. More information here: http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2290/what-does-the-filler-text-lorem-ipsum-mean.

Comment: One piece of real Latin in the jumble is from Horace: "parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus". The mountains are in labor (and) a ridiculous mouse wiil be born".

Comment: "The text is not a coherent passage" Google translate concurs (although I wasn't sure if that was by accident until I read your answer)

Comment: @stevec Google Translate is very poor for Latin, so I would expect even meaningful texts to produce garbage outputs (and some meaningless texts to produce coherent outputs). See https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/what-is-google-translate-good-for for more information.