# Translating "dangerous together" for a ring

Tags: motto, english-to-latin-translation

I would like to have the phrase "NN and NN — dangerous together" inscribed in a ring in Latin.
Google Translate suggests *periculosum simul* and *simul ancipitia*, but I'm not sure if they make any sense.
I would prefer to keep the original structure of the phrase, so I just want a translation of "dangerous together" to be used in such a romantic context.
What would be a good translation?

(Note: I received this translation request by email and asked it here to get more eyes on it than my own. This is why I also gave an answer myself.)

Answer (score 7):

First, [Google Translate is horrible with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), and doubt is wise.
In matters of any importance I strongly suggest consulting a person who knows Latin, and this site is a good option for it.

*Periculosum* is just the adjective I would use for "dangerous", but the form is wrong.
The best choice is *periculosi*; I will discuss options below.

I would read *simul* more as "at the same time" than "together".
The most fitting adverb for "together" I can think of is *una*, but I would prefer to use a participle.
My suggestion is *coniuncti*, which could be translated as "connected", "married" or "together".
(Spelling variant: *conjuncti*.)

My complete translation suggestion is this with a rough translation:

> *NN et NN — periculosi coniuncti*
>   NN and NN — dangerous when combined/married/together

I put both words *periculosi* and *coniuncti* in plural masculine nominative.
Masculine is the correct choice if at least one of the two people is male.
If both are female, then the words should be in feminine forms instead: *periculosae* and *coniunctae*.

One option to consider is to use all capital letters.
It often works well with Latin inscriptions, but the choice is of course yours.
If you do so, it is typical to replace every J with I and U with V (better leave the names as they are, though), so my alternative suggestion is:

> *NN ET NN — PERICVLOSI CONIVNCTI*

Comment: Just a couple of thoughts. (i) _Una_ means 'in unison', 'acting as one' and is a good choice here. (ii) In what sense  is 'dangerous' intended? Adding water to concentrated sulphuric acid is dangerous (or perilous), but I suspect that the real intention might be 'threatening' which, if so, you could better express by _minaces_.

Comment: @TomCotton Good thoughts! For some reason I prefer a participle, but *una* is indeed a good choice. I don't know what sense of "dangerous" was intended. If it was more threatening that perilous, I agree that *minaces* is a better choice.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility would be to interpret the phrase as a sentence:

> [We are] dangerous together.

For reasons I can't quite formulate, I don't like the sound of so many nominatives together. It has the sound of "NN and NN are dangerous joined ones."

My suggestion would be to use a verb, such as [*comminor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcomminor) (="threaten"), which happens to go quite well with *coniuncti*:

> NN et NN — coniuncti comminamur.

Another pleasing combination might be:

> NN et NN — uniti urgemus.

(N.B. *unio* is a rare, post-Augustinian word, so it may not be suitable for this context.)

Comment: _uniti_ ? Where did you find that?

Comment: Looks like it's post-Augustinian: [*unio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dunio1)

Comment: Apuleius uses it [once](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23uniti%23), though.

Answer (score 4):

Let me distinguish possible meanings of the original:

- **They are a danger:**
  If they are dangerous as a couple, they are a *dangerous union:* ***NN et NN: iugum periculosum*** (Bonnie and Clyde? Or like two wild horses attached to a *biga...*)
   If they are separately dangerous, and might even be a danger to each other, then ***NN et NN: par periculosorum*** (a pair of dangerous people, or change to ***periculosarum*** if they both identify as female: *par gladiatorum* is attested, a pair of gladiators fighting with each other... but Cicero has also *paria amicorum,* couples of friends...)
- **They are in danger**
   ***NN et NN: periclitantes iuncti*** (***iunctae*** if appropriate). We get a **very** slight difference in emphasis reversing the word order. ***Periclitantes iuncti*** is somewhat concessive: *even in danger, they stand together*; ***iuncti periclitantes*** is somewhat final: *they are together to face danger,* (but this is probably too subjective to be proven outside context).

After ***NN et NN*** a nominative is practically obligatory: good Latin style wouldn’t tolerate an adverbial apposition like *together* in English.  ***Iuncti*** is enough in this case: ***coniuncti*** reminds of ***coniuges*** and the English doesn’t say they are married.