# Translation for "Mortal willpower" (Tattoo idea!)

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

Or anything to a similar effect!

I was also considering something along the lines of 
Strength beyond Gods
or
Willpower beyond Gods/Willpower that transcends the gods

But, the original title phrase is what I'm primarily after.

I'm planning yet another tattoo, and I can't seem to find any existing lines out there for guidance, nor do I have the syntactical knowledge to be confident enough to craft something myself.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I would translate "willpower" as either *voluntas* or *animus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/9195/406), preferably the first one. (The second one is good specifically if you want to distinguish between "willingness" and "resolve".)

"Mortal" in the sense of "able to die" = "not divine" is *mortalis*; alternately, "human" = "not divine" would be *humanus*.

So the end result would either be *voluntas mortalium* ("willpower of mortals"), *voluntas humana* ("human willpower"), *animus mortalium* ("resolve of mortals"), or *animus humanus* ("human resolve"). I think I like the second one best, ***voluntas humana***.

Comment: That's a really great response! Thank you very much. The difference between Animus and Voluntas- what I'm intending the message for is in fact resolve, drive, determination sort of thing. Would animus therefore be more appropriate?

Comment: @Faz Both can be used in that sense! _Voluntas_ just has the additional meaning of "desire to do something", and _animus_ has the additional meaning of "mind" or "passion". Up to you which of those is more appropriate!

Comment: Awesome, I think I'll roll with Animus. You have been a great help, thank you sincerely.