# How can you translate the expression "Kindled embers" to preserve the meaning of smoldering chunks of coal or wood?

Tags: classical-latin, contemporary-latin, medieval-latin, academic-latin

I'm in need of translating this expression to Latin for a project of mine. I really tried figuring this out using Google but I came to a short end. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you give some more context? Do you want to use this phrase as a title or for something else? What do you want to mean by the expression? Translating short phrases well is often difficult if not impossible without context. (I can see why Google (Translate) is not very helpful with this. It is always [unreliable](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), and with anything non-trivial such as this one I really doubt its prowess.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word you want is *favilla*, which actually means 'glowing embers', or anything still hot and smouldering after combustion. As examples :

*ibi tu calentem debita sparges lacrima favillam vatis amici* (Hor. Odes 2.6.23)

And the well-known  medieval hymn, *Dies Irae, dies illa / solvet saeclum in favilla*.

Comment: Can I use “incendia favilla” for effect? Does it make it a pleonasm?

Comment: _favilla suscitanda_ would be better.