# Translation check: Servo libertatem vivere quate - Fortis est splendor infirma

Tags: translation-check, motto

I am creating a patch for my fictional team of heroes from the Terran Defense Force and I need to know if this translation is completely off or not.

I had to use machine translation so I need an expert vetting.

> Original text:
>   Keeping the torch of freedom alive — The Strong Protect the weak
>
> Translated text:
>   Servo libertatem vivere quate — Fortis est splendor infirma

I am asking here because I don't really have a lot of cash to throw around as converting my stories from shorts to comicbooks are sucking up a lot of my resources.

The text will be put on a patch on their arm so it needs to be correct.

I might even create a few patches IRL that I can hand out when I go to a comicon to present my comicbooks.

So you can understand it is really important for me the translation is correct.

I really hope someone can advice on the matter.

Comment: Maybe *Fortes custodiunt infirmi* for the second part?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Machine translations are [very unreliable with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), and I'm glad you are having it checked.
The offered translation is unfortunately quite nonsensical.

I would propose this Latin translation (with a literal English back-translation):

> *Pro viva face libertatis — fortes infirmos tuentur.*
>   For a living torch of freedom — the strong protect/support the weak.

To see details on the individual words I chose, you can consult any of [the many online Latin dictionaries out there](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).
The key words I used were *fax*, *tueor* (or *tueri*), *fortis*, and *infirmus* for "torch", "support", "strong", and "weak", respectively.
If you would like some word replaced by something you think has a more fitting tone, let me know in a comment.

If you want three plus three words for symmetry, I recommend:

> *Vivat fax libertatis — fortes infirmos tuentur.*
>   May the torch of freedom live — the strong support the weak.

The version *vivat fax libertas* (suggested by Hugh in the comments) is also possible.
It is not "torch of freedom" but more like "freedom the torch" or "freedom, our torch".
What is most appropriate is up to you.

To get an idea what the machine translation means, let me try to translate it back to English:

> *Servo libertatem vivere quate — Fortis est splendor infirma.*
>   I protect the freedom, shake living! — The weak brightness is strong.

It doesn't make much sense, since I can only translate non-Latin to non-English.

Comment: Great work, Joonas. But now that you've done all the hard work (and since brevity is the soul of wit) you could save a word. *Vivat fax libertas,* 'Long live the liberty torch.'

Comment: @Hugh Thanks! True, I could do that. I just felt that it worked best that the whole thing is a single clause with only one predicate, but it's certainly not the only option.

Comment: Really appreciate your suggestions, so the inscription on the patch would go something like this: Vivat fax libertas - Fortes infirmos tuentor.... ?

Comment: Would work quite well with 3 words on top arch and 3 words on lower arc - Will be creating a round arm-patch from the finally distilled version

Comment: @EinarPetersen If you want three plus three words, I suggest *vivat fax libertatis — fortes infirmos tuentur*. I will update the answer with some details later today, I hope.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta that sounds absolutely awesome - I hope you make sure to let me have some contact info so I can get a postal address at a later stage in order to send you guys a patch each for services rendered to the Terran Defense Force :)  as a thank you, once the project get's that far.

Comment: @EinarPetersen I updated the answer. I'm glad I could be of service! :) If you (or anyone) wants to send me something, my profile has a link to my homepage, and my work address can be found there. I will not share my private address here.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta - perfectly understandable and that is how we shall proceed