# How to translate machine learning?

Tags: word-comparison, contemporary-latin, technology, science, terminology

[Machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) is a roughly method where a machine learns to perform a certain task by learning on its own.
The machine gains experience and can solve a very specific problem intuitively.
It is not being educated by a teacher (other than its own experience) nor can it (unfortunately) communicate why it does what it does.

What would be a good Latin translation of "machine learning"?
The key aspect is choosing a suitable concept of learning to match what machine learning is all about.
For example, *educatio*, *studium*, and *eruditio* sound like a wrong kind of learning, but perhaps *cognitio*, *apprehensio*, or *discentia* might work.

The next step is bringing the machine into the picture.
It is probably easiest to understand if it is close to the English choice, for example *cognitio machinalis*.
Judging by the translations offered by Wikipedia, the word "machine" is included in most languages, and the most nontrivial part is a correct kind of learning.
The Romance languages are somewhat exceptional with "apprendimento automatico",  "apprentissage automatique", and similar.

How would you translate "machine learning" in Latin and why?
There are a couple of important aspects of the translation: understandability (at the cost of elegance if needed) and a descriptive choice of "learning".

This question was inspired by [a conference I am currently attending](https://earthscience.rice.edu/mathx2018/).

Comment: You better buy the domain within 10 seconds of the answer being posted....

Comment: @Dan If I had a machine learning start-up in mind, I certainly would. But I think I'll have to pass... :) (Also, if the first answer is generated by [Google Translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), I'd be betting on the wrong horse.)

Answer (score 4):

First, let's just note that the English phrase "machine learning" does not unambiguously communicate its meaning. If you had no context for it, you wouldn't know if it meant using a machine to learn, or learning about machines, or a machine doing the learning, etc. So, you've essentially asked for a translation that's more precise than the original phrase.

In fact, even the field of machine learning trades on a few different meanings. Sometimes it refers more to the efforts of researchers trying to teach machines to learn ("Machine learning is a booming research specialty"), sometimes it denotes the desired result, machines that are self-learning ("AlphaZero is a cutting-edge example of machine learning").

I think the best I can do without getting either extremely creative and inventing new words or making really unwieldy Latin is to offer you a way to say that a machine is self-taught. There is rare precedent for a Latin transliteration of a Greek term: autodidactus for αυτοδιδακτος. But it is available in Latin only as an adjective, so far as I am aware.

So:

machina autodidacta (self-taught machine)

ars machinae autodidactae (the field of study concerning self-teaching machines)

But if you're comfortable creating a new Latin verb, we have more options. Let's take "docere", the basic verb for teaching, and add our -auto prefix: autodocere, to teach one's self. I think the meaning will be clear to Latinists seeing it for the first time, though there may be some disagreement about whether it's proper to graft a Greek prefix onto a Latin verb.

This yields machina autodocta, which is equivalent to the previous suggestion. 
But we can play around with the verbal sense:

machina autodocens (self-teaching machine, a machine that is teaching itself)

ars machinae autodocentis (the field of study related to self-teaching machines)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not too fond of *auto-* with a Latin verb, but with the Greek stem it looks very good. Based on your suggestions, I am tempted to call the whole field of machine learning *[ars] autodidactica machinata*. A self-taught machine could well be *machina autodidacta* as you mention. // Regarding the first paragraph: I just wanted to make sure that no user tries to give me a direct translation, but rather tries to express the idea in Latin, and so I elaborated on the idea and desired tone. The English phrase is not perfect, and neither will a Latin one be.

Comment: I thought about _ars autodidactica_, but I'm not sure the adjectival construction allows more than two words, e.g., ars grammatica graeca. In order for there to be a three-word phrase, I think you need a genitive construction. Even there, I don't think _machinata_ works; it means "designed," which is where we get the word machine, a designed object. _Mechanica_ is the closest adjective, but its semantic range is quite broad. 

Really, if you wanted (which, I think you don't) a phrase that leaves intact the ambiguity of the English, the best is probably mechanica disciplina.

Comment: I agree, *machinata* is not good. The word I was after is *machinalis*. The *ars* can be left out, and the title *grammatica Graeca* is not uncommon. I modeled my idea of *autodidactica machinalis* on that. *Mechanica* is an option, but I'm a little afraid of the mechanical (instead of digital) connotations. Whatever I end up choosing (I'm in no hurry with it), your ideas are very useful.