# Gradient Descent and Backpropagation in Latin

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin

I came across [this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5890/how-to-translate-machine-learning) and was wondering if other terminology in artificial intelligence can be translated to Latin. Considering how deeply entwined the field is with science and philosophy, it is only fair for there to be proper scientific names for it like in biology :D

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you specify which terms you would be interested in translating into Latin? I don't think there's a general Latin term bank for this purpose, and "other terminology in artificial intelligence" is too broad. It usually works best to ask for one translation at a time and use different questions for different terms. This site works best with focused questions.

Comment: Specifically the terms: "Gradient Descent" and "Backpropagation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Propagation", as it happens, comes directly from the Latin verb *prōpāgō, -āre, -āvī, ātus*. A nice word for "backwards" is *rētrō*. So putting those together, you'd get ***rētrōprōpāgātiō*** "back-propagation".

"Gradient descent" is harder. English "gradient" comes from *gradior* "to go"; the native Latin word for "slope" is *clīvus, -ī*. I think in this case I'd back-form from the English and get *gradientia, -ae*, "gradient". Then "to descend" is *dēscendō, -endere, -endī, -ensus*. So "the descent down a gradient" is ***dēscensus per gradientiam***.