# Does "Ego Peccator" mean "I'm Sinner"?

Tags: classical-latin, translation-check

Does "Ego Peccator" mean "I'm Sinner"?
I used many web translation services but I'm still not sure.

Comment: If you're looking to translate "I'm a sinner" into Latin, consider "Peccator sum" or "Sum peccator". Making "ego" explicit adds emphasis: "Ego sum peccator". If you really want to grovel, "Peccator sum, Domine, peccator sum ego." If you google for any of these phrases, you'll find examples of their real usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Google Translate is notoriously bad with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), and to my knowledge others aren't much better.
Therefore it is always good to ask a Latinist, so I'm glad you found your way to our site instead of relying on online translators.

*Ego* means "I" and *peccator* means "sinner".
In Latin the verb "to be" can be omitted when clear from context, but it is still implicitly there.
That is, *ego [sum] peccator* means "I [am] a sinner".
The translation you have is indeed a valid one, whether the original has *sum* or not.

If there is another verb, then the *sum* is often no longer implicitly there.
Context, be it from other sentences or from this one being a part of a longer sentence, can change the meaning.
I only discussed the phrase in isolation.

Comment: Just a minor addition. By itself, _ego peccator_ means "I am a sinner." If you saw this in a sentence, it would probably be concessive or imply some other logical relationship. Ego peccator te Domine invoco. "I, though a sinner, call upon you, Lord."

Comment: @Kingshorsey Good point! I added a paragraph to mention the effect of context.