# The best way to say Sinners

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, plural

I'd like to create an aesthetic with the phrase "Remember that you must die, sinners" - targeted at the viewers. I know the first part is *memento mori*, but what is the best translation of "sinners"?
I **don't** want it to be only used in religion, **nor** for it to mean something like "defendant".

I found *peccatoris* and *peccatores* (what's the difference?) and *scelestus*, but I'm not sure if these are even correct.

Comment: _peccatoris_ is genitive singular, _peccatores_ is nominative/accusative/vocative plural. _memento mori_ is more literally the command: "remember to die"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See: [Does "Ego Peccator" mean "I'm Sinner"?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5921/does-ego-peccator-mean-im-sinner)

For the plural, it would be *peccatores*. *Scelesti* is more "the wicked," which is not the same as *peccatores* in Christian theology. In Romans 3.23, for example, Paul writes that:

> omnes enim peccaverunt
> For all have sinned

*Scelesti* however would be a sinner without redemption, someone who is wicked or deplorable. In 2 Timothy 3.2, they're labeled next to other degenerates:

> et erunt homines se ipsos amantes cupidi elati superbi blasphemi parentibus inoboedientes ingrati scelesti
> And men will be lovers of themselves, covetous, lofty, proud, blasphemous, disobedient to their parents, ungrateful, and wicked.

The other thing is that *memento* is for a singular subject. For the plural (because you have plural *sinners*) you want *mementote*.

Comment: Also worth noting that the word order is flexible depending on what effect you want to produce: I'd lean toward 'mementote, peccatores, mori' (commas optional) which feels the most dramatic to me.

Answer (score 5):

C. M. Weimer already treated the grammatical issues. However, in light of the fact that this question is tagged classical-latin, and that the author is specifically not looking for a purely religious term, I believe it bears pointing out that *peccator* does not appear to be a classically attested word. It was apparently used by Lactantius (around 250–320) and Tertullian (around 150–220), excellent Latin writers, but not classical and decidedly Christian. And it is of course all over the Vulgate.

A classically attested form would be *peccans* (plural: *peccantes*). For example, you have Nepos (Agesilaus 5):

> Cum [⋯] ut Corinthum oppugnaret multi hortarentur, negavit id suae virtuti convenire: se enim eum esse dixit, qui **ad officium peccantis redire cogeret,** non qui urbes nobilissimas expugnaret Graeciae.
>
> *When many urged him to attack Corinth, he said that this would not befit his chivalry; he was one, he said, to **usher the sinners back on the right path**, not to conquer the most famous cities of Greece.*

While surely not Christian at all, you can see that the idea of sinners as “people who have strayed from the path of virtue” is present. For a stronger expression of moral outrage, you might want to consider the term *nefarius* (from *nefas*, the universal Roman term for all which goes against the laws of gods, men and nature), plural *nefarii*.

Comment: Without it being clear from the question, I wouldn't put much weight in a tag from a new person. I know Lewis & Short offer "sinner" in translating *peccans*, but I think that's fairly anachronistic, and really doesn't fit with Nepos. Maybe in Seneca you can get close to it, but I haven't checked those references.

Comment: (But still good to note that *peccator* is not properly "Classical.")

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I guess the English word “sinner” can hardly be disentangled from the Christian context, and so the best Latin counterpart would be similarly entangled (which would be *peccator*), or else you are liable to end up with an anachronism.

Comment: That's my thinking, at least. If the OP wanted a Classical Latin reference for some reason (such as writing a story about Cicero), then a whole new set of doors would be open, including *nefarii*, *scelesti*, and *peccantes*.