# Help translating "The way forward is the way through"

Tags: sentence-translation

I'm interested in getting a Latin translation of the following: "The way forward is the way through." (Think of having to overcome a difficulty — to move forward you have to go through the difficulty.)

I came up with *est via deinceps quod est via per* but I feel like this is not correct.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I hope you will register your account and take a look at our [tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour). Now that you got a couple of votes for a good question, you earned some [privileges](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) like voting. Most importantly, I hope you find the site useful and stick around for more questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about ***prodire est transire***, "to go forward is to go through"?
Instead of "way", I used the verb *ire*, which I think fits nicely.
You should check whether [*prodire*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2047914) and [*transire*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2060343) sounds suitable either using the links or picking any of [the many online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).

It would be tempting to translate "to go through" as *perire*, but this verb actually means "to die", "to perish", and similar.

Your translation suggestion sounds much like Google Translate, and [it is horrible for Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79).
A far more reliable way to come up with mottoes in Latin is to find two words in an actual Latin dictionary and translate "X is Y" as *X est Y*.
And of course the best option of all is to ask on this site…

Comment: Yes. Google Translate and Latin left me uninspired to say the least. Thank you for your motto creation suggestion.

Comment: @John I'm glad to be able to help!