# "Obeying the law" in Latin

Tags: motto

How to say "Obeying the law" or "we will obey the law" in Latin, as something like a slogan?

Comment: *"Tolle legem,"* 'Grasp the Law.' (overheard in a garden in North Africa, nearly)

Comment: Welcome to the site! That's a nice question, but in order to be on-topic in Latin.SE, you need to show your previous efforts in translation. You might want to start by checking a [good online Latin dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/867/which-online-latin-dictionaries-should-i-use-and-why), or even [Google translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/what-is-google-translate-good-for), though our (perhaps unanimous) advise is not to trust it too much.