# How would you say "only when you forget you are human will you remember you are a god"?

Tags: sentence-translation, motto

Title says it all:

I'm looking to translate the English motto "Only when you forget you are human will you remember you are a god." to Latin. Due to the grammar and phrasing of the clauses, [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com) which I usually turn to is completely unhelpful.

Comment: Now that you got 15 reputation points, you can vote any questions and answers you like on the site. The feedback is always welcome! If your question has been answered satisfactorily, you can accept an answer by ticking the green check mark next to the answer. I hope to see more questions from you! For more information on site mechanics, please consult [our site's introductory tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest:

> *Modo te hominem esse oblitus recordaberis te deum [esse].*

The key words are the participle *oblitus* ("one who has forgotten") and the verb *recordaberis* ("you will remember").
It says "only as someone who has forgotten you will remember".

Forgetting and remembering have objects expressed by an accusative with infinitive.
I put the objects around the two key verbs to create a chiastic effect.
You could translate *te hominem esse* as "that you are human" and *te deum esse* as "that you are god".
The second *esse* is optional.
So is the first one, really, but I would keep it for clarity.
Choose what sounds best to you.

I should add that what I wrote can be said to a man.
If the addressee is female, then replace *oblitus* with *oblita* and *deum* with *deam*.

[Google Translate is indeed horrible](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79) even with simple sentences.
The only thing it seems to translate semi-reliably is individual words, and for that purpose [online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) are far better.