# How to translate "in truth, beauty"

Tags: sentence-translation

How should I translate "in truth, beauty" to Latin? It is similar to how *in vino veritas* means "in wine, truth." I don't know much about Latin and Google Translate wasn't very helpful. It suggested *vero forma*, but this didn't translate back to English properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Translate is horrible with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), and this is yet another piece of evidence.
The correct way to translate by analogy is to understand the structure and replace the words.
Google Translate seems to be incapable of this, which is bewildering.
The suggested translation seems to have nothing to do with what you wanted.

In the phrase *in vino veritas* ("truth [is] in wine") we have "wine" in ablative and "truth" in nominative.
To translate "beauty [is] in truth", we need "beauty" in nominative and "truth" in ablative.
(The word "is", *est*, is often left implicit in Latin, and Latin word order is different from English. Therefore I find "truth is in wine" or "there is truth in wine" to be an accurate translation of *in vino veritas*.)

Especially if you want to do something similar to the well known Latin quote, *veritas* is a good choice for "truth".
There are a couple of options for "beauty", and I suggest starting with *pulchritudo* and *amoenitas* (coming from *pulcher* and *amoenus*).
You can check the two words [in any online Latin dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) and compare how the translations back to English differ.
For a quick comparison, I would say that a person can be *pulcher* and a scenery can be *amoenus*.

Depending on what kind of beauty you mean, I suggest: ***In veritate pulchritudo/amoenitas.***

Comment: You could replace "beauty" with "logical beauty." As a mathematician, I think you'll understand what I mean by this. Of the two suggestions, I think "In veritate amoenitas" is closer. Do you agree? Based on this new information, do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @RandyRanderson I agree that in that case *amoenitas* is indeed the best choice.