# On the basis of "Veni, vidi, vici" is "Veni, bibi, oblidi" remotely correct?

Tags: conjugation

When using [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com) or [eprevodilac](https://en.eprevodilac.com/prevodilac-engleski-latinski) from Latin to English, both tools translate the following phrases as shown:

- Veni, vidi, vici → I came, I saw, I conquered (Google Translate)
- Veni, vidi, vici → I came, I saw, I won (eprevodilac)

The other way around gives the following (notice that both translations omit the commas):

- I came, I saw, I conquered → Veni vidi vici (Google Translate)
- I came, I saw, I conquered → Veni vidi vici (eprevodilac)

For the sentence I want to translate, results are as follows:

- Veni, bidi, oblidi → I came, I drank, I forgot (Google Translate)
- Veni, bidi, oblidi → I came, I drank, I forgot (eprevodilac)

The other way around:

- I came, I drank, I forgot → Veni, bibi, oblitus sum (Google Translate)
- I came, I drank, I forgot → Veni, bibi, oblitus sum (eprevodilac)

My questions:

- Why does the translation "seem to work" from one language to the other (i.e., Latin → English), but not the reverse?
- If the translation for "I forgot" is "oblitus sum" ([which seems to be the passive indicative perfect tense](https://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?T1=obliviscor&Submit=Go&D1=9&H1=109)), why isn't the "I conquered" translation "victus sum"?
- Is the translation of "I came, I drank, I forgot" to "Veni, bidi, oblidi" remotely correct, or not at all?
- Bonus questions: why are the active indicative and subjunctive so rich for "[víncere](https://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?T1=vinco&Submit=Go&D1=9&H1=109)", but almost nonexistent for "[oblīvīscēns/oblīvīscéntis](https://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?T1=obliviscor&Submit=Go&D1=9&H1=109)"? Can't "to forget" be [active](https://www.thoughtco.com/example-sentences-of-the-verb-forget-1211169) in Latin?

I hope my questions are not too stupid...

Comment: A machine translation question where the robot actually produces correct Latin! That almost never happens.

Comment: Edi, dormivi, saltavi, iteravi.

Comment: The lack of commas in the translation may not be a surprise. We should be glad that there are spaces as word boundaries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Bonus questions: why are the active indicative and subjunctive so rich for "víncere", but almost nonexistent for "oblīvīscēns/oblīvīscéntis"? Can't "to forget" be active in Latin?

All natural languages, Latin included, have some irregularities. You just discovered one here, except it's backwards. It's not that the active is missing with *obliviscor*, rather, it lacks active *forms*.

*Obliviscor* falls into the category of verbs known as deponent verbs. These verbs look passive, but they are in fact active in meaning. There are a whole slew of these verbs, including *loquor*, *sequor*, and *gradior*. These verbs are usually indicated as such in the dictionary with with "dep." somewhere or otherwise just giving the principal parts without active forms, such as *obliviscor, oblitus*.

There are also semi-deponent verbs, which lack active forms in the perfect tenses, but otherwise have active forms in the present tense. Their principal parts will reflect that, too, so *gaudeo, gaudere, gavisus*.

> Why does the translation "seem to work" from one language to the other (i.e., Latin → English), but not the reverse?

[Google Translate is not a good tool for Latin.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/what-is-google-translate-good-for) I strongly recommend against using those tools to discover a language's grammar. It can't even get [vocabulary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16882/the-meaning-of-scelerisque) correct, and grammar, as you've seen, breaks down when going outside what it "learned."

> If the translation for "I forgot" is "oblitus sum" (which seems to be the passive indicative perfect tense), why isn't the "I conquered" translation "victus sum"?

So, because *obliviscor* is deponent, it's active in meaning but passive in form. Meanwhile, *vinco, vincere* is not deponent. Its passive forms are also passive in meaning. *Victus sum* means "I was conquered."

> Is the translation of "I came, I drank, I forgot" to "Veni, bidi, oblidi" remotely correct, or not at all?

No. There is no such word *oblidi* in Latin. [Edit: Oops, this is a Latin word, as cnread points out in the comment. But it is rare and unrelated to *obliviscor*, and instead comes from *oblido, -ere* 'to crush'.]

It does sound like *obliti*, but by itself that would indicate the perfect participle in the masculine plural or genitive singular.

Comment: (Actually, there is a word oblidi; but it's the present passive infinitive of oblidere and therefore means 'to be squeezed' or 'to be crushed.')

Comment: @cnread Thanks! If I ever had come across that word, I had since forgotten it.

Comment: It's not just Latin. If you make a mistake in verb forms in Google translate in the original language, it will translate it without any reference to the mistake. *I have taken, I has taken, I have took, I has took, I took, I taken* all translate to *j'ai pris* in French.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers and all the comments. So can we say that "Veni, bibi, oblitus sum" is the correct translation for "I came, I drank, I forgot"?

Comment: @pdeli Yeah, `oblitus sum` is the correct translation, although if the speaker is a woman, it would be `oblita sum`.

Comment: @McKinley Gratias tibi valde!