# Does this translation make sense?

Tags: classical-latin, translation-check, english-to-latin-translation, motto

I am in charge of a professional chiropractic fraternity, and I would like to have coins made with the Latin version of "sincere fellowship in chiropractic medicine" on the coin. This is the best I have come up with. Does this make sense?

> sincera in communione medicina chiropractic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The suggestion you gave is the one given by Google Translate, and it does make very little sense.
[Google Translate is very unreliable with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), and should as a matter of principle never be trusted.
A much better translation is often obtained by looking up the words one by one in [any online Latin dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).
If it is anything important, please always check the translation with someone who knows Latin.

The first and most important step is to find the correct words.
Here is a suggestion:

- **fellowship**: A good word for a fellowship, association, union, community, or society is *societas*. The word *communio* does not seem to refer to an organization, at least not as clearly as *societas*.
- **chiropractic medicine**: A good general word for medicine is *ars medicina* or simply *medicina*. To specify that it's the chiropractical kind of medicine, an adjective is needed. Although it is almost certainly not classical Latin, the (originally Greek) adjective *chiropractica* seems appropriate.
- **sincere**: Perhaps *fidelis* would be appropriate? It means trusty, sincere, or faithful. There is also *sincerus*, but it doesn't seem to be very close to the English "sincere".

Putting all of this together with the correct forms gives:

> sincere fellowship in chiropractic medicine
>   *societas fidelis in medicina chiropractica*

If you want to drop the word "medicine", you can simply drop the word *medicina*.
The implicit *ars* goes well with the plain *chiropractica* as well.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! Now say if I wanted to drop the medicine, would I still be able to use "chiropractica"?

Comment: @MaxGatzke You're welcome! Yes, you would. I just expanded my answer to cover that.

Comment: Thank you again! I know I already asked a question of you, but since you have been the most helpful, I was wondering if you could answer this; how would I say "fraternity officer"? Would it be officini fraternis or fraternis officini?

Comment: @MaxGatzke It's best to ask that as new, separate question. That way people can easily see it and weigh in. (Also: In addition to voting all questions and answers you like, you can mark an answer to your question as accepted by ticking the little green mark next to the voting arrows. That shows that the case is closed, so to say.)

Comment: Oh my apologizes. Thank you for you comment on that