# Translation check: propter scientiae amorem

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation, motto

The good people over at latindiscussion have been helping me with a project I'm working on. Now that I'm nearly finished, I would like to double check the results.

Take the motto:
"propter scientiae amorem"

Please tell me:

1. How does this translate to English? (*Please, no machine translations.*)
2. Is it grammatically correct?
3. Is it too ambiguous to be understood?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How does this translate to English? (Please, no machine translations.)

It translates to "for the love of science".
The exact wording might depend on context.
(Indeed, [Google Translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79) and others are quite horrible.)

> Is it grammatically correct?

It is!

> Is it too ambiguous to be understood?

Not at all.
I can only think of two sources of ambiguity, and neither is significant:

- The word *scientia* can mean science, knowledge, and other such things. It is not clear whether it refers to scientific things or knowledge in a broader sense. But for most purposes this distinction is irrelevant in a motto.
- On can interpret "the love of something" in two ways: the something loves or is loved.
  The Latin *amor alicuius* has this freedom.
  But in this case it is pretty clear that love is felt towards science, not by it.

Comment: I started with "For the love of knowledge." I'm happy to see it can mean both.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @fieryace I'm happy to see a well-thought question from a new user and glad to be able to help! I hope you'll stick around and ask more questions.