# Is this "Veni vidi vici" spin-off translation correct?

Tags: translation-check

Sorry if this question seems silly, I do not know Latin...
I wonder if someone can help me with the proper translation for:
"I came,
I attended,
I left"

With the help of google translate i got something like this:
"Veni,
Attendi sum,
ego abierunt"

Now, is that correct?

Comment: I don't know Latin either. I got this from translate.google.com: "I came, I attended, I left -> Veni adtendi reliqui". Translated back is interesting: "Veni adtendi reliqui -> I came so look survivors".   With commas, makes even less sense: "Veni, adtendi, reliqui -> I came, I set my mind on, the rest of the".  Guess the tool needs some work!

Comment: @CrossRoads I think it doesn't just need work, it needs a complete restructuring. [This question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79) investigates the failure of Google Translate with Latin in some depth.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it isn't correct.

*Veni, adfui, abii* — literally I came, I was there, I went away.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! @Tom Cotton

Comment: Somehow imperfect _aderam_ seems preferable to perfect _adfui_.

Comment: @Colin Fine  Why? All three actions are complete, _i.e._ perfected, and in the past. Why single out adfui? Would Caesar have written _veni, videram, vici_?

Comment: The semantics are different. _venio_ and _vinco_ are punctual, or at least telic. _video_ could be punctual or extended. _adsum_ (in contradistinction to _adeo_) is stative. But I accept that it loses the parallelism.

Answer (score 8):

For reference, here's what you *did* write:

> Veni

I came

> Attendi sum

[Attendi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attendi) is either the first person perfectum *I have attended* or a second person present or imperative, *you attended* or *do attend!*. Sum is just 'I am'. Since you can't have two finite verbs in a sentence, I would think there's some ellipsis involved like "I have attended [for] I am".

> ego abierunt

Latin verbs don't need an explicit subject: *veni* means *I came*, not just *came*. In case "ego" is included as a subject (and it is, because ego is the first person nominative), it means to convey emphasis. However, [abierunt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abierunt) means "They have left', so the subject and verb don't match.

All in all, it sounds like a small child who is upset that everybody left when they came, and is having trouble talking while crying at such indignity:

> I came, I have attended... I am... (sniffle) They left *I*!"

Comment: "*veni* means *I am*" I think you meant "*I came*." (I tried to edit the post but the fix was under the minimum number of characters. :-p )

Comment: @LarsH Yep. For your entertainment, I edited in such a way that you _could've_ done without hitting the minimum character limit. ;)

Comment: Good. I don't like adding unnecessary changes to someone else's post in order satisfy that rule.

Answer (score 1):

Tom Cotton's *Veni, adfui, abii* is pretty good. In this case, one might also use the pluperfect forms of *venio* and *adsum*, as: *Veneram, adfueram, et abii*, though if you are looking for some kind of motto or something similar, that does take a little bit of the "ring" out of the phrase.

By the way, [Google Translate is terrible for Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79); it cannot render correct parts of speech or forms for agreement. Those who study Latin know to never depend upon it.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for the answer! I took the liberty to add a link to another question where Google Translate is explored more. Can you explain why you would choose pluperfect? It is a possibility, but it would be nice to have an explanation of the change in meaning.