# How to modify 'inter arma enim silent leges' to mean 'in a time of crisis, the law falls silent'?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I know the popular phrase

> *inter arma enim silent leges*

means

> in a time of war, the law falls silent.

I want to modify the phrase to say 'in a time of **crisis**, the law falls silent'. I've not studied Latin before, but using Google translate gives this:

> *in discrimine tempus, quod cadit lex tacet*.

This seems suspect to me, as the translated sentence structure is way off the '*inter arma enim silent leges*' form. In fact, Google translate gives '*in tempore belli, quod cadit lex tacet*' for 'in a time of war, the law falls silent'.

My question is, **how do I say 'in a time of crisis, the law falls silent' to have the same structure to 'inter arma enim silent leges'?**

Comment: *quod cadit lex tacet means "because it falls the law is silent; so 'wrong sort of fall.'

Comment: Do not use Google translate for Latin, just don't.

Comment: @VladimirF [I fully agree.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to find a good translation for "crisis".
There is the Greek loan *crisis*, but I would go for a more Latin option.
The best choice depends on what kind of crisis is meant.

My suggestion is ***tumultus***, which Lewis and Short translate as "uproar", "violent commotion", "sudden or impending war", "sedition", "rebellion", "anxiety", "disturbance", "agitation", "disorder", and other similar terms.
If the crisis is at the level of national politics or security, this is a good word.
If the crisis is more personal, then *tumultus* would have to be taken as a figure of speech or one would need a different word.

Literally, *inter arma* means "amidst weapons".
The preposition *inter* ("between" and similar) sounds less appropriate for *tumultus*, and I would replace it with *in*, which here would mean "in time of".
Therefore *inter arma silent leges* would become ***in tumultu silent leges***.

Answer (score 2):

*Crisis* seems to be an attested Latin word (e.g. [here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=Crisis&la=la&can=crisis1&prior=amor#lexicon)), derived from [Greek](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CF%81%CE%AF%CF%83%CE%B9%CF%82#Ancient_Greek). It's used in [Wikipedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_pecuniaria) too.

However, a more popular word seems to be *[discrimen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discrimen#Latin)*, as Google told you. This is attested in Classical Latin (e.g. [here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=discrimen)).

So, I would say either

> inter crisis enim silent leges

(if we take it as indeclinable; otherwise, it might follow the Greek declension rules, being *crisin*) or

> inter discrimen enim silent leges

Notice the [original order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_arma_enim_silent_leges) of the phrase (from Cicero) was *Silent enim leges inter arma*. Order of words generally makes little difference in Latin, so you can stick to the more famous version.

Comment: The original literally means "among arms, the laws are silent." Your translation seems to me to mean "among crises, the laws are silent." I don't think that's really what OP is trying to say.