# "No virtue in being a humankind" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

For a cartoon project about a veterinary office, I need to translate below phrase into Latin. The shorter, better as it’s going to be the slogan/motto.

"No virtue in being a humankind."

It literally means humankind is no higher than other creatures.
I found these so far: *nulla virtus in humanum* (this one so far looks the best) OR *nulla virtus in homine* OR *homines*.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you tell us what you have tried already? E.g. what words have you found? It is great that you already provide the context, by the way: that really helps. I wonder about *a humankind*: what do you mean by that, exactly? It sounds a bit odd to me (but I'm a dog...).

Comment: Hi, thnx!! It literally means humankind is no higher than other creatures. I found these so far:

nulla virtus in humanum (this one so far looks the best)
OR
nulla virtus in homine OR homines

Comment: OK I understand. It would be great if you could add that to your question, so that answerers may see it.

Comment: In clear: try to translate the sentence first by your own, and give us the result.

Answer (score 4):

I was thinking along the same lines as Nickimite. The first sentence of Sallust's *De coniuratione Catilinae* says:

> **omneis homines, qui sese student praestare ceteris animalibus**, summa ope niti decet, ne vitam silentio  transeant veluti pecora, quae natura prona atque ventri oboedientia finxit.
>
> 'It's fitting that **all humans who are eager to stand above all other animals** strive with all their might not to pass through life un-talked-about, like cattle, which nature has fashioned face-down and obedient to their stomach.

By saying 'all *other* animals,' Sallust acknowledges that humans themselves are just animals (though we're capable of rising above the level of the rest through effort). There's also I nice contrast between standing (the root of *praestare*) and being face-down (*prona*). I suggest an adaptation of this sentence – for example:

> **homines minume praestant ceteris animalibus.**
>
> 'Humans don't stand above all other animals.'

Other arrangements of the Latin sentence are possible – for example:

> **minume praestant homines ceteris animalibus.**

This version emphasizes the negative: 'It not at all the case that humans stand above all other animals.'

> **ceteris animalibus minume praestant homines.**

Since the verb *praestare* literally means 'to stand in front of,' the word order of this version helps underscore the meaning of the sentence by actually putting the rest of the animals before humans.

**Update:**

Since this answer has now spawned [a related question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13004/is-there-any-difference-between-minime-and-minume), I'll point out that I used the form *minume*, instead of the more commonly seen classical form, *minime*, solely because I was adapting a passage from Sallust, and he uses such 'archaic' forms as a matter of style. It can easily be replaced with *minime* without any change in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

For "no virtue" as in "there is no virtue", the phrase *nulla virtus* is great.
The harder decision is what to follow it with.

The only grammatical one of your suggestions is *in homine*, "in human".
That would amount to "[there is] no virtue in a human".
If that matches your intention, you can go with that.
The options *in humanum* and *in homines* don't work.
If you want the plural "in humans", use *in hominibus*.

One word worth considering is *humanitas*, meaning "humanity" or "human nature" or "mankind" or other similar things.
My suggestion is ***nulla virtus in humanitate***, "[there is] no virtue in mankind".
The word order ***in humanitate nulla virtus*** also works (thanks TKR!).
I think that captures the original idea quite well.
The word *humanitas* has a wide range of meanings, some of which are more positive that you would like here, but I would not consider that an issue; the fact that there is no virtue in it puts it in suspicious light anyway.

[Do not trust Google Translate with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79).
It is very unreliable, and often suggests nonsensical translations.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Not yet very familiar with how this site works so pardon me if I’m no using the commenting feature properly. I’m now between Humanum and Humanitate. According google translate, Humanum translates to Human Race (which I mean exactly) but Humanitate means Humanity. Humanity itself can mean either “Human Race” or “Humaneness; benevolence”. I think the second meaning (Humaneness) which has a positive feeling is more common for humanity & people use mankind/humankind/human being usually to refer to human race. So according this don’t you think Humanum is more appropriate?

Comment: @ALY. [Take a look at our introductory tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn the basics of the site functionality. [Do not trust Google Translate with Latin at all](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), as the results are horrible. The option *in humanum* is not valid Latin. If you want to say "in human" or "in humans", say *in homine* or *in hominibus*. It is indeed true that *humanitas* as a wide range of meanings, but it also includes the human race. I would still consider *in humanitate* best, but *in homine/hominibus* is also possible.

Comment: Joonas, what do you think of the word order alternative *In humanitate nulla virtus*?

Comment: @TKR It's a very good alternative. I edited it in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say that humankind doesn't go above other creatures, a good translation would be

Homo omnia non superat.
"Man does not conquer all things"

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quite difficult to find out a proper translation without betraying the Latin and classical spirit!

In the Latin world the importance of animals is mainly about what they represent: love for example (the *passer* of Catullo to Lesbia), they are messengers of human feelings. 
But they can also represent human virtues and vices, stereotyped and even stigmatized behaviors (just think to Phaedrus and its fables).

Nevertheless, if you are looking for an exact translation to "No virtue in being a humankind", we can easily express it as

*Nulla virtus in esse homo*.

However, I would suggest also another sentence, that in my opinion strictly links humans and animals, without removing any virtue from both. No classical reference, just me, so see if you may like it...

*Homines prosint animalibus et animalia hominibus*, meaning "Let humans be of benefit to animals, and animals to humans"; which probably is also related to the office in question and the veterinary work.

Edit 15/12/2019:

> Note that, in classical Latin at least, you can't make esse (or any other infinitive) the object of in (or any other preposition). Or perhaps this is a Medieval or later construction that aims to imitate a Greek articular infinitive?

You are perfectly right, this construction is Medieval:

[image]

In his *De decem praeceptis* (Collatio V), S. Bonaventura writes "In esse naturae filius non est coaequus patri". There are also other examples of the same expression, even stronger than the often used in philosophy *in esse, in posse*.

As written in the comments, I took the freedom to choose the use of the nominative case. In general, this is not a mistake; in some grammars, where sometimes impersonal examples are displayed, it's easy to find the verb as an infinitive, and the subject in nominative:
[image]

Certainly, if we had an infinitive sentence (such as a subjective or an objective), we could only use the accusative case for the subject of the verb, but here, in the phrase I wrote, we have a substantivized infinitive, which does not make the sentence an infinitive one.

Comment: Note that, in classical Latin at least, you can't make *esse* (or any other infinitive) the object of *in* (or any other preposition). Or perhaps this is a Medieval or later construction that aims to imitate a Greek articular infinitive? I do quite like your second translation, though I'm not sure it very accurately captures the sentiment that the original poster is trying to express.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I perfectly agree with you. Yes, I'm aware that mine is quite a risky attempt, on the line of the Medieval *in esse*, *in posse*, etc. It is true that I took the freedom of using esse as a nominal predicate accompanied by a noun and not as a verbal one

Comment: Ah, so it is a Medievalism then. Interesting. And would nominative case be used for the predicate noun with such an infinitive? In classical Latin, an accusative would be used. So, for 'To be a human is x', I'd say esse hominem est….

Comment: The verb *esse* is never transitive, so we cannot use an accusative; we should say *esse homo est...*, where *homo* is the one who accomplishes the action or the state expressed by the verb, although the subject of the whole sentence is *esse homo* itself.

Comment: @cnread **For the use of nominative:** this comes from a relatively recent book, *Logica Magna: fascicule VIII, part 1: Tractatus de Necessitate*. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJCUl.png, while this other comes from an older work (*De Aristotelis casu et contingenti. Dissertatio inauguralis, etc*): https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjGA9.png

Comment: Normally yes, of course, *esse* is intransitive; but that doesn't apply in the case of my example. The subject of an infinitive is accusative, and therefore, a predicate noun/adjective is also accusative, even if, as in my example, the accusative subject isn't explicit. So *esse hominem est...* is correct. In Allen & Greenough's Latin grammar, this rule is given in section 452, Note 2. I'm perfectly willing to accept that the nominative is used in the Medieval construction; I was just wondering whether that's the case.

Comment: And actually, the two examples that you link to are quite different from the example that I gave, and also from the translation that you gave in your answer, because the esse is a complementary infinitive; therefore, the sentence structure is really just an extended instance of nominative subject + copula + predicate noun (also nominative).

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. What I was pointing out is that my sentence is not an infinitive construction with accusative, and the examples were meant to show that if we don't have an infinitive there's no way to use the accusative with *esse*

Comment: I just looked up at the grammar you mentioned, and that's something I didn't know. Maybe we can say that the sentence non esse cupidum est pecunia is just an unusual case of infinitive, but please let me know your opinion

Comment: The ex. in AG may be a tad obscure (Cicero, Paradoxa stoicorum 6.51), but I don't agree that its use of the inf. is unusual; it's a natural extension of the ideas that 1) subject of inf. is acc. and 2) complement is in same case as noun it complements (though that noun isn't expressed here). In fact, Cic. does this 3 times in a row, so it's no mere fluke: non esse cupidum pecunia est, non esse emacem vectigal est; contentum vero suis rebus esse maximae sunt certissimaeque divitiae. The less-obscure ex. I'm familiar with is Sallust, Iug. 31.27: nam inpune quae lubet facere, id est regem esse.

Comment: At any rate, this is getting off topic. If the construction that you used is Medieval, and if that Medieval construction uses the nominative case for predicate nouns/adjs. with esse, so be it. I rarely read Medieval Latin, so I'm not familiar with all the ins and outs of its grammar. I don't suppose you can update your answer to provide an example of the 'in esse' construction that you used there (or the 'in posse' construction that you referred to in an earlier comment)?

Comment: @cnread sry, i meant an unusual case of infinitive sentence, I got confused since in English the verb and the type of sentence are called the same. Nevertheless, I edited the answer; there are only a few examples that can be found on this topic, that is quite spiny imo. Again, the examples for the nominative are not specifically related, they are just meant to justify the use of nominative, if we do not have an infinitive sentence.

Comment: The examples numbered 489 and 490 struck me as bizarre, not just for the infinitive verbs but because the nouns and adjectives are all in the nominative. I would have made 489 _Sunt homines nomine tantum, non re, qui homine indigna faciunt._ How could there be so many errors? Google found the sentence in a book titled _Exercises to the Accidence,_ consisting of sentences lacking proper inflection, which the student must correct. This might explain those two examples (but not the others). What do you think?

Comment: Wiktionary suggests that _esse_ in Medieval Latin became used as an indeclinable noun meaning state or condition. So, _in esse naturae_ would mean "in the state of nature". This sounds like it calls for a new question!