# Composer requesting help with a perfect translation

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, song-lyrics

Ave, Latinstackers!

I am writing a three-part piece in Latin for my choir, and I want a perfect, exact translation of the text into Latin, please. I strongly suspect that Google translate has not got it quite right!

Here is the text. I would be extremely grateful to anybody who  would spend a moment to give me the exact translation of each line.

> Fire is coming.
>   Drought is coming.
>   The dust rises,
>   and our sky is obscured.
>
> Floods will come.
>   Frozen rivers will flow.
>   The city of Venice is drowning;
>   and what are we doing?
>
> We will act.
>   We will all change,
>   and we pray that our world will recover.

Thanks in advance from Cantus Lupum

Comment: Could you tell us first how you think it could be translated?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the exact translation" of anything. Even a literal translation is only possible if there is enough context to deteremine which of the possible equivalents is most appropriate - and when I talk about the "possible equivalents", I don't mean just the choice of words, but also the grammatical relationships.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ask for a translating, without really asking a question.

Answer (score 10):

I apologize if this comes across as a non-answer, but I cannot help giving it.
I have translated several songs into Latin for professional singers.
Good translations take a lot of work:

- I make sure the singer is comfortable with the translation. I add or remove syllables or avoid words they find awkward for some reason.
- I make the rhyme, alliteration, and rhythm work in a way comparable to the original.
- I pay attention to whether it sounds good to a listener who knows no Latin.
- I make sure there are elements that are easy to grasp, like well known Latin words or names.
- There is no such thing as literal translation of song lyrics, so I have to decode the message and recode it in Latin. This involves not only shifting to another language but often also shifting to another cultural context.
- I repeatedly discuss the translation options with the singer to find solutions that work well on all levels. It often takes a large number of iterations to get it right.
- I check carefully that the text is grammatically valid.
- I provide a detailed pronunciation guide and teach the singer until satisfied.
- I abandon some projects as I cannot make them work in Latin in a way that meets my quality standards.

Although I do like to offer volunteer help on this site, this amount of work is too much.
A "perfect translation" is possible get, but probably not something you can easily get from a professional for free.
I fully understand that not everyone has the will or ability to pay for such services, but quality work costs money.

Perhaps someone can offer you a quick translation.
But don't expect it to be fully polished and conveying exactly the intended message.
To end on a positive note, [you are wise to doubt Google Translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79).

Comment: This is great, but--isn't this an answer to a different question? I would think the current question, as stated, should be closed, though I'd love to see this as an answer to a different question!

Comment: @brianpck I agree. I'd be happy to repost this answer to a differently focused question. I can ask myself, but I'll be more than happy if someone beats me to it.

Comment: Thanks, everybody.  Let me clarify; I am an amateur composer, working with my own small women's A capella choir for 20 years.  My work is entirely voluntary and the singers make a donation, so there are no spare funds for anything fancy.  As the song is in the form of short sentences, rather than complex prose, I was hoping that a straight-forward translation, paying attention to tense, and of course; intention of meaning, would be possible.

Comment: @brianpck Personally, I think that this answer is 1. the correct answer to this question, in the context of this website; just because it wasn’t what was desired doesn’t make it the “right” response to give, and 2. better given “naturally” in a case where it was requested than “artificially” in a question designed for this answer. Personally I’d say it’s best where it is.

Comment: Whether this question should be closed is a matter to be settled by voting: If you think it should be closed, flag the question for closure or vote to close. That's the way it's designed to go.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Thought this had been answered; eager to read the translation, alas. There is a prescient comment on Venice, sadly.

Answer (score -1):

Ignis Venturis est. - Fire is coming.

Ecce Ignis. - Here is fire.

Ad nimium venturis est. - Drought is coming.

Ecce Ossa - Here are bones.

Et pulvis resurget, - The dust rises,

et nostras caelum obscuratur. - and our sky is obscured.

Inundationes veniet. - Floods will come.

Sentire aquas. - Feel the waters.

Gelida flumina et influunt, - Frozen rivers will flow,

et civitas venetiarum submersus est - and the city of Venice is drowning.

Quid agimus? - What are we doing?

Nos agere! - We act!

Agere debemus! - We must act!

Nos omni mutatione oportet. - We must all change.

Orationi instate, qui, ut noster orbis terrarum recuperat. - Pray together, people, that our world can recover.

*Thanks Latinstackers.  Please highlight any glaring errors. Any kind assistance with this small private project would be received with deep gratitude.  CL.*

Comment: Now what was it you said about google translate?

Comment: Thank you fdb; I have to assume from your oblique comment that this translation will not be too wildly inaccurate to incooperate into an amateur musical score.  I will proceed using this text.  Please close this question, Latinstackers.  Sorry to bother you all.

Comment: btw, fdb; I compared a lot of results from a lot of Latin translation sites to arrive at this basic translation.

Comment: No, you have misunderstood me. Your translation is completely and utterly wrong.