# "Hunt like a wolf, feast like a god" -- is the Google translation correct?

Tags: idiom, translation-check

I want to translate this to Latin:

> hunt like a wolf
>   feast like a god

Google gives me

> sicut lupos venari
>   a deo quasi festum

To my understanding, the words are pretty much correct, but does this translate my idea?
I want to say "Those who hunt like wolves, will (or are able to) feast like a god (or gods)"

Comment: An entry for the 'questions you can answer from the title alone' gallery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are my preferred alternatives:

*Qui sicut lupi agitant epulantur sicut di.*

or

*Par lupo venans dive epulatur*.

Here's how I got there:

The relative clause seems more idiomatic to me.  After all, one typically says *qui tacet consentire videtur*, not *tacens consentire videtur*.  However, the construction with the participle is also perfectly correct.

"Like" in the sense here is regularly expressed with *sicut*, thus *Qui sicut lupus agitat sicut deus epulatur*.  Frankly, I think the plural might sound even better ("like gods" is less awkward than "like a god"): *Qui sicut lupi agitant sicut di epulantur*.  Note the nominative forms after *sicut*.  *Sicut* is a conjunction, not a preposition, but the verb is understood in many situations, including this one--no need to repeat *agitant* or *epulantur*.  Finally, I'd probably want to emphasize the nouns rather than the verbs, so I'd rearrange to *Qui sicut lupi agitant epulantur sicut di*.

Examples of *sicut* used in this way include *Plagas sicut Thomas non intueor* in Aquinas's hymn *Adoro te devote*, but looking *sicut* up in Lewis & Short you will find plenty of examples of this usage in Cicero, so it's definitely classical.  I think it's fine to use *par lupo* to describe "[hunting] like a wolf"--it really means [hunting] equally with a wolf.  I do not at all like *par deo* to describe "[feasting] like a god", since the point of "feasting like a god" is not that you are equal to the gods in feasting but that the feast in front of you is like a god's feast.  Also, it seems awkward to have the adjective *par* modifying the same subject (*venans [homo]*) twice.  So the closest to Joonas's translation that would sound right to me would be *Par lupo venans epulatur sicut deus*.  If you want to keep it as brief as possible, you could probably say *Par lupo venans dive epulatur*.

Answer (score 6):

Nope!
[Google Translate is very unreliable with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), and this suggestion is gibberish too.
I'll refrain from trying to analyze the Google suggestion and offer something else instead:

> Par lupo venans
>   par deo epulatur.

This is best translated to English as:

> The one who hunts like a wolf
>   feasts like a god.

English isn't very good at capturing the structure, so perhaps the Finnish will be more illuminating:

> Suden veroisena metsästävä
>   jumalan veroisena juhlii.

I wanted to use the same structure on both lines to get the strong parallelism of the original.
Therefore I prefer either *par* with *par* or *sicut* with *sicut*.
I chose *par* because it felt stronger; it seems to me that *sicut* is more "in the manner of" and *par* more "with the prestige of" (in Finnish: kaltainen tai veroinen eikä vain samalla tavalla).
(Your question also reminded me of the poem *ille mi par esse deo videtur…* by Catullus.)

Comment: Pisteet suomesta! Please can you refer to where or how you came up with this solution?

Comment: @Sami A poem by Catullus came to mind and suggested using *par*, but it's mostly a result of years of studying Latin. Unfortunately I don't know any other way to translate well. I did consult a couple of dictionaries, including the Finnish one by Pitkäranta and one online. Jos tähän onneen olisi oikotie, olisin varmaankin jo löytänyt sen...

Comment: I think the poem had something like "Mihi par deo videtur" which means "to me he seems like a god"

Comment: @Nickimite I added the first line of the poem in case anyone wants to search it.

Comment: @Sami After sleeping the night, I now updated with a little explanation.