# What does "Vivamus vel libero perit Americae" on Hannity's new book mean?

Tags: translation-check, book

Sean Hannity is coming out with a new book called *Live Free or Die: America (and the World) on the Brink.* At the bottom is a perplexing subtitle in Latin:

> **VIVAMUS VEL LIBERO PERIT AMERICAE**

Here's the title page:

[image]

My question is simple: **What does this Latin phrase mean?**

Comment: Yes...I'm being a bit tongue-in-cheek, but this is pretty hilarious

Comment: It certainly has a hilarious aspect to it, but I find it more saddening. They wouldn't have had to pay much to a Latin teacher or student to get something sensible.

Comment: Oh dear, someone used google translate instead of finding an actual translator. What a hack job (I refer to the translation; I'll leave my feelings about what the book itself will be like unmentioned).

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta He wouldn't have had to pay anything at all to the people here at the Latin StackExchange, or any other on-line forum about Latin. It frankly shows his contempt for his audience.

Comment: @JasperMay Indeed, one could get free assistance also. What I meant was that for a little fee you could be sure that someone who knows the language commits to the translation. I agree, the choice of tools shows contempt.

Comment: Bemoaning the poor attempt at Latin is beside the point of the book cover. In a country where a significant proportion of the population believe that the unalterable Authorized Word of God was written in English in 1611 (or alternatively, that the original text of the US Constitution has the same status as a Holy Book), who cares anything about ancient languages?

Comment: @alephzero—Well, King James was one of the apostles.

Comment: "The people called Romanes they go the house??"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### That's not a simple question, because this is not a real sentence

[Perditianus on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/gkqyxn/sean_hannity_thought_some_latin_would_add_a_bit/) pointed out on May 16 that this is exactly what Google Translate gives for “Live free or America dies”.  So it seems likely that this piece of text was not composed in Latin by any human author.

I don’t think “What does this mean” is a clear question when applied to a sequence of words produced in this manner.

- If you consider its meaning to be the meaning intended by the author of the English text that was entered into Google translate, then it probably means “Live free or America dies”.
- If you consider its meaning to be what a reader without knowledge of its (likely) origin would guess it means, that seems to depend on the reader. It doesn’t seem to have a clear single meaning in that sense (i.e. it's a jumble of words).

#### The publisher replaced it with "Vivamus liberi ne America pereat"

As more evidence that “Vivamus vel libero perit Americae” was not the product of any intelligent thought process, it has been replaced since this post was made by "Vivamus liberi ne America pereat." ("[Hannity Removes Latin Nonsense From Book Cover](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/news-and-features/articles/hannity-removes-latin-nonsense-from-book-cover/)", by Michael Schaub, Aug. 7, 2020, *Kirkus Reviews*)

This implies that not even the publisher considers “Vivamus vel libero perit Americae” to have a sensible interpretation in terms of standard Latin grammar.

Comment: What would be the right way to translate "live free or america dies"?

Comment: *Liber vivas aut moriiaris*, maybe?

Comment: @Nacht-ReinstateMonica Perhaps that'd work better as a separate question? It'd be a pity to bury such a question and its answer(s) in comments here.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I asked because I thought it would improve this answer, to show how wrong the nonsense Latin is.

Comment: The original question was, What does "VIVAMUS VEL LIBERO PERIT AMERICAE" mean? But this answer does not answer that question. It only says that this Latin is produced by GT on an English phrase, possibly one of many, that is different from the book title. And in this case it's obvious that GT is wrong (e.g. *Americae* is not nominative singular, etc.). So what on earth is the relevance of this answer to the original question?

Comment: @LarsH I think there's a more charitable interpretation: it's well known that Latin Google Translate produces gibberish, so the (understood) conclusion of this answer is: "It's a word salad that doesn't mean anything."

Comment: @brianpck This argument has so many gaps it's hard to even know what fallacy was intended.

Comment: @LarsH It's an [*enthymeme*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthymeme), not a fallacy. (Unless you think one of the premises is false!)

Comment: @brianpck Since the unstated premise of an enthymeme is unstated, it's hard to be sure which premise was intended. One good guess is the premise "Latin GT *always* produces gibberish." This is impossible to verify, but easy to falsify: try translating "I came, I saw, I conquered." Since that unstated premise is false, it's possible that the argument attempts to leap from "Latin GT *sometimes* produces gibberish" (and "This string was produced by Latin GT") to "This string is gibberish", which is indeed (also) a fallacy.

Comment: If you think there is a different understood premise that makes more sense, I'm interested to hear it. I agree that the Latin phrase is nonsense, by the way... but your answer does a good job of showing that by analyzing the Latin, whereas this answer doesn't shed light on the subject.

Comment: @LarsH You could say this is our (the internet's) best guess what the author intended to express with those words. So it does, sort of, answer what the sentence “means.”

Comment: @Sebastian Even if the author's intent were the primary component of what the sentence *means* (dubious, if the grammatical and lexical meaning of the words is at odds with the author's intent), the fact that phrase X run through GT produces phrase Y does not mean the author intended phrase X. There may be many other variations that when run through GT produce phrase Y.

Answer (score 20):

As the other answers indicate, this is nonsense. But I think it would be helpful to provide (1) a parsing of the nonsense Latin, and (2) a good translation of the intended phrase.

## Parsing of nonsense Latin

- vivamus: 1st person plural subjunctive, "let us live"
- vel: (inclusive) "or"
- libero: this can either by the 1st person of [*libero*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlibero) ("I deliver/free") or the dative/ablative singular of [*liber*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dliber1), which is either an adjective meaning "free" or a noun meaning "child."
- perit: 3rd person singular indicative: "he/she/it perishes"
- Americae: genitive/dative singular or nominative plural of "America."

The phrase doesn't fit syntactically even into a nonsense sentence. But here's the best sense you could make of it, if you are generous with the dative "libero" and interpret "Americae" as genitive (h/t to Sebastian for pointing out that the locative wouldn't work for a country):

> Let us live or it perishes for a free person of America.

## What's a good translation?

I suspect that the intended phrase is just ["Live free or die,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_Free_or_Die) and that "America" from the  subtitle crept into it. This is the state motto of New Hampshire, used in English during the American Revolution. According to the linked article, this phrase in term comes from the French "*Vivre Libre ou Mourir.*"

Cicero has a sentence in the *Philippics* 11:24 that is parallel:

> nunc quod agitur agamus. agitur autem **liberine vivamus an mortem obeamus, quae certe servituti anteponenda est.**

My translation:

> Now let's treat the issue at hand. The issue is whether **we should live free or we should undergo death, which is certainly preferable to servitude.**

Changing this a little bit, a concise Latin translation of "live free or die" is:

> **Aut vivamus liberi aut moriamur.**

...which is:

> **Either let us live free or let us die.**

An even nicer sounding alternative from the above Cicero quote, which strays a bit further from the English:

> **Mors servituti anteponenda**

...which is:

> **Death is preferable to servitude.**

Comment: `Mors servituti anteponenda` said the slave owner Cicero.

Comment: @user28434: Many (most?) illuminists were slave owners since "some men cannot make good use of reason". It's not that easy. Not to mention that, in Cicero's time, slaves performed services which in modern times have been automatised or facilitated by technology. Of course that's not a justification, but it did take much technological and social progress to get rid of slavery.

Comment: @user28434 Jefferson faces similar rebukes. While we can and ought to hold historical figures to the standard of timeless moral principles, we should do so with caution: "canceling" Cicero because he believed some reprehensible things is hardly the proper attitude to the mistakes of those who preceded us. (Nor do I think you were suggesting that!)

Comment: One option would be a neuter, impersonal gerundive: "si serviendum erit, moriar Americae fidelis" = "If it must be slavery, let me die loyal to America".

Comment: How do you feel about a translation like "Aut vivamus liberi aut moritur America", in an attempt to recover what Hannity (or the intern at Hannity's publisher) was trying to say?

Answer (score 16):

Nothing.
I think it's [Google Translate nonsense](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), but it's perplexing that it'd find its way to a cover.

The results may depend on the user, but I get these translations:

- Live Free or Die: America > Free aut mori; Americae
- Live free or Die: America > Liberum vivere aut mori; Americae
- Live Free or die: America > Free aut mori; Americae
- Live free or die: America > Mori aut liberos vivere: Americae

Capitalization alone changes the suggested translation wildly.
Google suggests many translation variants for the individual words.
Translating the words in isolation gives somewhat but not wholly different results; e.g. *vivamus* is one of the suggestions for "live" and you can get *libero* (the verb) from "free".
It sounds very likely that the translation you quote came through Google, perhaps with someone trying to pick something that sounds nice.

While one can try and translate it, I would consider such an endeavor quite pointless; it was not put together as a coherent Latin phrase so I would not analyze it as such.

Comment: No, it's not perplexing at all that it would end up on a Hannity book cover. Not even a little bit. *sigh*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Perhaps you'd then count me blessed, as this question was the first time I heard of him. Better first impressions have been made to me...

Comment: When translating back to English the translator gives me "FREEDOM OF AMERICA lives or perishes".