# What is the best translation for 'Future Earth'?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Using Google and other online dictionaries I came up with 'Terrae Futurum'.  Is this the best way to present the idea of how the Earth could look in the distant (billion years) future?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [Google Translate is horrible with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79) and is not to be trusted.
It has relevant components to it, but the details go awry.
If you want a reliable online Latin dictionary, [check this list of ours](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).

The word *terra* is more like "land", "country", or something of that kind.
For the whole planet the more suitable word is *tellus*<sup>1</sup>.
This is a feminine word, so the adjective<sup>2</sup> *futurus* should go into the singular feminine form *futura*.

It is possible to use *terra* as well, but I find *tellus* more appropriate.
There seem to be regional differences in preference, but both are valid options.
They both take the same form of the adjective.

The future Earth is thus ***tellus futura*** or ***terra futura***.

---

<sup>1</sup>
The plural is *tellures* instead of *telli* if you need it; don't be fooled by its ending in *-us*.

<sup>2</sup>
It's really a participle, but it can be treated as an adjective for many practical purposes.

Comment: It should be noted that _Terra_ is more easily recognisable as a scientific name of the planet, and its use with this connotation is attested even classically. For instance, in Quintilian's _Institutio Oratoria_ [we find](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/quintilian-orators_education/2002/pb_LCL126.189.xml): _Quaeritur per coniecturam... : ‘an sol maior quam terra...'_ ("We use conjecture... is the Sun bigger than the Earth...").

Comment: @VincenzoOliva That's a surprise to me. Around here people would recognize *tellus* as the scientific name for our planet, not *terra*. There are regional differences, but it's true that both options work. My preference is *tellus*.

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Comment: In the US, "Terra" is the only widely recognized scientifical name for the planet. I didn't know that "Tellus" was recognized (by non-classicists) anywhere.

Comment: @Nickimite In Finland I had learned Tellus as a scientific name of our planet as a kid, perhaps a decade before I ever encountered the word *terra*. I'll edit the answer a bit to give both options.