# Help translating "It's not a bug, it's a feature!"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, translation-check

I know no Latin, but playing around with Google Translate I came up with "Non insectum opus est". *Insectum* seems like a good stand in for a generic bug, but maybe *blatta* is better (see http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/bug.html)? And opus carries the connotation that the entire program is as designed.

Comment: As a counterfactual study into the matter, I wonder if there is any language that translated 'bug', 'feature' and is using as a standard in daily language. I feel like all developers just gave up and they are using all these terms in English anyway. So if Latin was alive, it could possibly take the same road. I think, to have these words in Latin, we would need to first author many software books in Latin to have a real playground, otherwise everybody might invent their own. Might be good to find some examples in internet to see if people intuitively came up with the same words.

Comment: @oguzalb I'm no developer, but in normal Finnish I'd express "not a bug but a feature" as "ei vika vaan ominaisuus", which literally has the somewhat broader meaning of "not a fault but a property". Words like this exist in many languages, including Latin, but their meaning is rarely confined to software.

Comment: @oguzalb: you seriously underestimate us, French people who decided to rewrite computer language so that the world may have a laugh. The French word for "bug" is "bogue" (http://jargonf.org/wiki/bogue - it is actually the name of the spiky cover of chestnut and was allegedly chosen as such on purpose)

Comment: It needs to be noted that "It's not a bug, it's a feature" is often used as an excuse for re-categorizing the perceived aberrant behavior.  And sometimes it's used in a jocular fashion.

Comment: @WoJ well the same approach is also tried for Turkish in some universities, and those scholars are actually teaching with those words. I mean words that also cover "register", "chip" etc and Turkish is not based on Latin words, so they are totally new and very different to the English ones. But those don't reach to the actual sector, people generally make fun of them
Thanks for the link though, I can read some French, will have a look, will be very interesting

Comment: @oguzalb: we have a culture of strongly protecting our language. This is sometimes great, and sometimes simply ridiculous. There was an official dictionary of computer-related words built in the '90s. Some of the words proved that the writers were clearly under influence when they invented the words. Some others caught up. Today we use a mix, sometimes several words for one action (say, to reboot will be *rebouter* (an anglcism - it will be written as *rebooter*), or *redémarrer* (restart)).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Google Translate is unreliable with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79) and you should not take anything it gives seriously.
The suggestion *non insectum opus est* sounds like "an insect is not work".

I am not aware of good Latin words for "bug" or "feature".
Therefore I would take a different approach and suggest:

> *Non forte sed ratione.*
> Not by chance but by design.

Another option is to go with participles:

> *Non ruptum sed designatum.*
> Not broken but designed.

If you refer to something specific, remember that the Latin participle needs the correct form (gender and number).
As just a general rule without referring to any single thing, I think singular neuter works well.

You can also substitute *erratum* (misstep, mistake) for *ruptum* (broken).
This should be seen as a noun (*errare* is intransitive, so *erratum* is best seen as a derived noun rather than a participle).
If you want to shift nuance from "broken" to "misstep", you can say *Non erratum sed designatum*.

Comment: Playing off of that format, which to me retains the general flow and feel of the english, what about something like _Non comminutus sed ratione_, "not broken but by design".

Comment: @Adam I think the parallelism works better if you have two participles, "not broken but designed". How does *non ruptum sed designatum* sound?

Comment: I like that! This is a phrase I encounter at work a lot, so I'm very familiar with the original. Oh, one additional I idea from my wife: _non erratum sed designatum_

Comment: @Adam I haven't checked carefully, but my impression is that *errare* is "to take wrong step" rather than "to break". Which one is more appropriate depends on context, but I think breaking fits a little better. But I'd be happy to see other suggestions! There must be a number of nouns, participles, adjectives, and adverbs one could use.

Comment: "Wrong step" is absolutely perfect for a programming bug!

Comment: @ManicPolymath I added a note on that.

Comment: Perhaps "not by error but by design", which (I think?) would be something like `non errato sed designato` (ablative, rather than nominative).

Comment: or perhaps use *intentio*?

Comment: There are some nice suggestions in these comments. They should be given as other answers; I'm happy enough with mine and I don't think I'll expand further.

Comment: The problem with this excellent answer is that the phrase "feature, not bug" is used to refer to the properties of software that were in fact **not** designed. Usually this phrase is used to express "I didn't intend for it to be that way, but the code is already written and I'm satisfied with its behaviour even if you are not". In Hebrew, lacking the word "feature", I would substitute the word "advantage". Other viable words might be "trait", "property", or "difference" if Latin has those words.

Comment: @dotancohen Oh! I always took it so that the saying referred to the program working as planned despite the user thinking otherwise. The key message here is: If one asks a translation question and wants specific nuance, the nuance must be explained explicitly in the question. With no explanation, we can't really tell what the intention here was. I'd be happy to read if anyone wants to take the point of view you propose and write a second answer.

Comment: When I asked the question I had indeed thought about "feature" being "as explicitly designed", but I am curious what the Latin would be for "not a failure, but a happy accidental success".

Comment: @ManicPolymath To get visibility for that question, I recommend asking it separately as a new question. I would be curious to read the answer(s) too!