# Follow up "It's not a bug, it's a feature"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

Following up [Help translating "It's not a bug, it's a feature!"?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14492/help-translating-its-not-a-bug-its-a-feature), *non erratum sed designatum* came up as a great way to say "not a wrong step, but working as designed" as in "the process or sequence seems wrong, but is in fact as it should be". *Non ruptum sed designatum* has connotations for "the thing looks broken, but is in fact working as it should".

Also during discussion it came up that the English idiom is also (or more) valid for "that may have been wrong or unintentional, but that's really how it should be". An example of this might be [Nuclear Ghandi](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/nuclear-gandhi), where a bug "ascended" to be such a part of the original *Civilization* game that later versions emulated the "incorrect" behavior. Would this be *erratum crevi* for "the error has been promoted", or does *crevi erratum* give a better emphasis: "promoted, the bug was"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Non error, sed adiunctum*

Not a mistake, but an essential feature (or attribute).

Edit: I attempted to answer what I saw was a question, but now see as more of a post.

Comment: I like it. Out of curiosity, why did you go with _error_ instead of _erratum_?

Comment: Erratum is from the perfect passive participle of Erro, Error is the noun. So erratum would technically be "Something mistaken" and not "a mistake" There is a difference of tone. But I also like to be more laconic in my Latin renderings.

Answer (score 3):

*O Felix culpa, o necessarium Adae peccatum!* (O happy fault, O necessary sin of Adam!)

This is a paraphrase of a line from the *Exsultet* which captures (in extremely florid and poetical language) some of what you are aiming at. I hope it helps, or at least inspires!

Comment: Oh that is nice. I'm keeping _felix culpa_ around for later.