# Does 'sonic' really translate to GENIUS in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

English to Latin google translate seems to work for most words, but the translation from English "sonic" seems odd to me (a Latin non-speaker/reader/writer):

[image]

Is this accurate, and if so, what is GENIUS? (and why is it in all caps?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No!
The Latin word *genius* means something like a spirit, and has nothing to do with "sonic".
[Google Translate is not to be trusted at all with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), and you have found yet another piece of evidence of this.

The word *sonic* comes from the Latin word *sonus*, "sound".
From this noun you can derive the adjective *sonicus*, "sound-related", but it does not appear in classical Latin.
In any case, I think ***sonicus*** is the best Latin translation of the English "sonic".
And this should make sense; a sonic boom is a boom related to sound.
It has nothing to do with "genius".

Comment: *Google Translate is not to be trusted at all*. Period!

Comment: Can we have a tag for collecting bad Google Translate examples? I can see myself using these as an example for something in the future

Comment: @Nacht The best list is the [list of questions linked to the Google Translate question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4349?lq=1). At least I've been linking to it actively to build that repository of examples. If you'd like a tag, I suggest asking a meta question.

Comment: @Nacht a tag could be useful. Especially if google eventually uses it to identify incorrect translations

Comment: @stevec I strongly encourage you to write up a meta question about such a tag. I wouldn't want to hide such a discussion in these comments.

Comment: JoonasIlmavirta and @Nacht, I created a question [here](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/461/tag-specifically-for-incorrect-google-translate-translations). Please feel free to edit it as necessary

Comment: @Shaggy While I would not trust a machine translation for something that really mattered (company motto, tattoo, contract), it is also true that Google Translate can produce very usable results for many pairs of modern languages. The Latin feature though seems to be a bit of a gag/proof-of-concept that is not identified to the users as such.