# Translate "the sweetness of the stars" into Latin

Tags: translation-check

I need assistance in putting together a title for a music album. I came across the much used phrase "ad astra" which is so beautiful to me, and I wished to write something like "the sweetness of the stars", which google tells me is written as "dulcedinem ad astra". Is this correct? If not, how would it be written instead? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You should know that [Google Translate is no good for Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79).

"Of the stars" would generally be expressed by a genitive plural form, *astrorum.* "Ad astra" roughly means "to the stars".

I don't think you should use the form "dulcedinem". Latin inflects nouns for their role in the sentence. "Dulcedinem" is specifically the form of "dulcedo" that would be used for the object of a verb. The subject of a verb would use the form "dulcedo".

The form of a Latin noun considered to be the default is usually the form used for the subject ("nominative"). Unless you have a specific reason to use another form, you should use the nominative when you're using a noun phrase in isolation, outside of a sentence.

So the correct grammar to express "the sweetness of the stars" with the words that you are using would be *dulcedo astrorum.*

You could also express this idea with other words. Latin has a number of words for *sweetness.* According to Lewis and Short, *[dulcedo](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/dulcedo)* is often used in metaphorical senses ("pleasantness, agreeableness, delightfulness, charm"), and somewhat rarely used in the literal sense of "something sweet to taste".

Another option would be *[suavitas](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/suavitas),* which also is often used broadly, in the senses of "pleasing to the senses" or "pleasing to the mind".

Comment: Excellent answer! I edited in a link to the Google Translate question; I had intended that to be a universal question about that tool so that others can refer it for further details and credibility (of the claim that Google is unreliable).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I didn't trust google for sure, but sadly latin is a thing I have no knowledge of, or anyone that I know lol, so I truly appreciate your reply. 

If it were up to you, what other variations would you suggest that run along the same lines of what I'm trying to translate? My interest is both in accuracy and aesthetics.