# Translation of "auxilium nullum secundum"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, motto

I have tried to translate "auxilium nullum secundum" to English through Google but it doesn't appear to capture the true meaning.

This is an organizational motto on a patch (military patch) so this is not a part of a longer sentence.

Comment: If you haven't already, I suggest [going through our quick intro tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour). It'll guide you through some key features. You can always accept an answer to your own question to indicate that the problem is settled and you can vote up any questions and answers you like when you're logged in.

Comment: Looking online, this appears to be the motto of of the Operations Support Squadron, and the translation given is 'Support second to none'. However I would have expected 'second to none' to be 'nulli secundum' not 'nullum secundum.' Has someone slipped up?

Comment: @Afer I only just now saw your comment. I added a discussion on that to my answer a moment ago. I reached the same conclusion that a dative would make more sense.

Answer (score 5):

Latin mottoes tend to be terse and open to several interpretations.
Changing a single letter can drastically alter the reading and the composer of the motto may or may not have been fluent in Latin, so it may well happen that none of the offered translations actually match the original intention.
Mottoes can be hard and in some sense impossible to translate and [Google translate struggles with even simple sentences](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), so don't expect it to give anything sensible for a cryptic input like a motto.

With that out of the way, here are some ways to read it:

1. [*Auxilium*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=auxilium&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) is "help", *nullum* is "no" or "none" or similar, and [*secundum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=secundus1&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) has several meanings but the most common one is "second". There can also be implied words that are not written out, such as *est*, "is". Whatever the translation is, it is composed of these elements, and these alone give some sense of what it tries to say even though the words as a mere list do not constitute a translation.
2. Reading *secundum* as *sequens* (it has meanings close to a participle of *sequi* as it comes from *sequundus*), my interpretation would be "no help is following" or more fluently "no help will follow", meaning "we have to manage alone".
3. If we read *secundum* to come from *sequi* with a passive sense (this is common for even for deponent verbs, but *secundus* has to some but not full extent detached from *sequi*), then this means "no help is to be followed" or "we must not follow any help". Perhaps the eventual meaning comes close to the previous one.
4. *Auxilium* can also be interpreted, especially in a military context, as "auxiliary unit". With this I would read the motto as "no auxiliary unit follows" or "no auxiliary unit should be followed" (active or passive version, cf. points 2 and 3).
5. As Adam points out in a comment, the official translation seems to be "support second to none". This is indeed a possible reading, more (too) literally "support that follows nothing". This interpretation is fathomable, but I would have expected a dative *nulli* to go with *secundum* instead. I think the accusative requires reading *secundum* more verbally than adjectivally.
6. Yet another alternative is to read *secundum* not as the adjective or numeral but as [an adverb or a preposition](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DS%3Aentry+group%3D24%3Aentry%3Dsecundum).
   The adverbial reading gives something like "no help is behind" or "no help comes after us".
7. If we want to take *secundum* as a preposition, it should be positioned like one.
   If we take quite some liberty and read it as a postposition, it means "after" (in rank, time, or something else) or "according to".
   This gives the reading option "help according to nobody" or "nobody things we're helpful".
8. If we take the "after in rank" reading of the postposition, we get something like "help second to nothing".

Different interpretations 1–4&6 lead to quite different literal translations, but the message seems to be roughly the same: "We need to manage without help."
The official one, the fifth one, is quite different, and out of the rest only number 8 matches it.
Reading 7 turns it around to be quite negative.
This is what Latin mottoes are like!

Many of these readings are quite charitable and do not constitute good Latin in my opinion.
The most natural readings don't correspond to the official one and no reading strikes me as particularly natural, so I would consider the motto to be ill-composed.

Comment: I did a quick Google search of the phrase and found the [emblem itself](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:910_Operations_Support_Sq_emblem.png) on Wikimedia commons. According to the file description it seems to have been intended to mean "support that is second to none". Is that a possible reading of this, or should the case of _nullum_ and/or _secundum_ be changed?

Comment: @Adam Thanks! That does make sense and I added it to my list. It strikes me as the least sensible reading on syntactical grounds, but it is very reasonable in content.

Comment: The only way to make the phrase work (sort of) as it is, is to construe secundum as the preposition, which does take an accusative object and can mean 'second to'; the catch, of course, is that we'd have to assume that it's being used as a postposition instead of a preposition. Certainly, it's fairly easy to imagine some poet moving the preposition that means 'second to' after its object for special effect. Still, I think you and Adam are correct that nullum is a mistake, and that it should really be nulli (or, according to OLD, a nullo).

Comment: @cnread Indeed, I had ignored the prepositional reading as *secundum* was not prepositioned. I added more readings to my list. Very few of the readings are natural by any measure, but sometimes these mottoes require quite a bit of charity from the reader.