# What is the best translation of the phrase `plebs together strong`?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I think the phrase `plebs together strong` is a cool one in English, but I'd like to translate it to Latin. In this context, I take `pleb` to mean `a commoner, an ordinary person` and the essence of the sentence to have a similar meaning to `apes together strong`.

Here are several translations I've found on Google Translate (English to Latin):

```
`pleb together strong` --> `pleb validis pariter`  
`pleb strongest together` --> `pleb fortissimum simul`
`pleb together undefeated` --> `pleb simul invictam`
```

I did see a translation that had the word `invictus` in it that I liked; I can't recall what it was.

EDIT: It was `pleb simul invictus`, meaning `pleb together undefeated`. However, when I translate that phrase from Latin to English, I get `he wished, at the same time he was unconquered`.

Of course, I don't understand `excrementum` in Latin; I would just like to not completely embarrass myself when I plaster something on a t-shirt and rock it around town.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: [Google Translate is horrible with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79) and its suggestions are not to be trusted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google translate is awful, so don't trust it for Latin (and many other languages, I've noticed).

The word you're probably looking for here is *plebs*, not *pleb*. In English, "pleb" is short for "plebeian," which in turn comes from the adjective form of the Latin *plebs*. It means "the common people, the masses." I'm not really sure "apes" means that in the parlance of GME shareholders, but it makes sense in and of itself.

Strong is *fortis*, but I really think the comparative is better: *fortior* "stronger". You have a variety of options for "together." The most common are probably *simul* or *una*. The former is "at the same time," whereas the latter can also mean "at the same place, at one." Additionally, you have some prepositional phrases with *unus*, like *ad unum*. You could even imitate the English and do it as an appositive, which would be *una* again, but with a short -a on the end (unā, that -ā being long, is an ablative).

Taking it all together, an option for you is **plebs fortior una**, "the common people are stronger as one" or with slightly different and perhaps better word order (as suggested by TKR), **plebs una fortior**, "a united people is stronger."

Comment: Yes, I was trying to capture the sentiment of the GME holders but in a different context... I do like the idiosyncratic feel of that phrase and I also like that `pleb` or `plebs` is the first word. Thank you!

Comment: How do you feel about the participle *unita* instead of *una*? I'm not sure if there's a significant difference in this use.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Well [unitus](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23unit) is a pretty rare word, *uniter* aside, and not present in Republican authors.

Comment: The alternate word order *Plebs una fortior* strikes me as preferable here; an English translation would be "A united people is stronger".

Comment: @TKR I think you're right. I was sort of playing with *e pluribus unum* as a parallel, but I agree that reversing the two is indeed preferable. I think I'll add it.

Comment: I don't know if this affects anything, but memetically, it is 'strong', not stronger.  It's a sense of: "apes alone weak, apes together strong" rather than "hedge funds strong, apes together stronger", if that makes sense.   I also don't know if *memetically* means: of or relating to memes, but it should.

Comment: @mcalex In that case, using the same vocabulary I offered, you would only need to make *fortior* *fortis* instead.

Comment: @mcalex I still think "stronger" works, too: "We're stronger together than separate."

Answer (score 11):

Note that *plebs*, although it stands for many people ("the common people", "the multitude"), is a singular noun, both in English and the original Latin. The plural is usually not used (although sometimes in Latin, in that case it's *plebes*). Therefore, there is no single *pleb*; a member of the *plebs* is called a plebeian, or *plebeius* (*-a* if female) in Latin.

The English phrase you cite has a babytalk feel to it, presumably because it is supposed to mimic the meaning of the character's gestures. I am not sure if you want that recreated in Latin, and would not really know how to do it anyway. So let's assume you want normal, correct Latin.

A suggestion: **Concors valet plebs.**

*Concors* means "united, of a mind." *Valere* means "be strong" (although it also has other meanings like "be well").

Alternatively, you can take inspiration from Sallust and say (Bellum Iugurthinum 10):

> Concordia parvae res crescunt, discordia maximae dilabuntur.
>
> *Through unity small things grow, through disunity great ones fall apart.*

If you want it to look extra cool, you can say *maxumae* instead of *maximae*, which some sources have (it is an older form).

Comment: Good call on *valet*. I like this translation.

Comment: I agree with cmw about valet. The choice of concors is also spot on. (I like the word order too.) In short, your translation is a thing of beauty.

Comment: @cnread Sane erubesco ;-)