# How would I write “Apes Together Smart”?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

“Apes together Strong” is a phrase from planet of the Apes. I’m trying to reword it to say “Apes Together Smart” or apes that are united are smart.
For reference, I’ve researched and found that concors valiere simias means apes are stronger in concert, but I want to write Apes Together Smart.
The previous information was gathered from [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15992/what-is-the-best-translation-of-the-phrase-plebs-together-strong) Thanks!

Comment: So you're asking how to translate something which iw not English into something which is not Latin, right?

Answer (score 2):

*Simii una sollertes* in my humble opinion manages to translate something that is not quite good English into something that is not quite good Latin, to borrow a phrase from a commenter. *Simii* means "apes", *una* is an adverb meaning together or in one place, and *sollertes* is one of many Latin words which can be translated as "smart". *Callidi* or *sapientes* might also do, depending on what you are getting at.