# Everything is as it should be

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I am looking to translate this phrase to Latin

"Everything is as it should be" or "Everything is what it should be" would be fine too.

Google translate gives me "omnia ut sit" but when I flip latin to english, "omnia ut sit" translates to "all things that it may be"

I have found that "omnia debet esse sicut esse" translates to what I desire in English, but I know nothing about Latin, and this just does not look correct to me.

I have tried a few different translators online but have not managed to find any consistency.

Comment: Thanks for joining the site! Google translate is [notoriously bad](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/what-is-google-translate-good-for) at translating to and from Latin, unfortunately, so it's good that you're questioning what it gives you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one option:

> Omnia ut oportet sunt.

- *Omnia* is "all things, everything"
- *ut* is "as"
- *oportet* is an impersonal verb meaning "it is proper, (one) should/ought to"
- *sunt* is "are" (plural because "all things" is plural)

Put together, this literally means "All things are as is proper / as they ought to be". I've placed the verb "are" at the end because Latin often does that, but you could equally well say *Omnia sunt ut oportet*, with a more English-like order.

ETA: as Joonas says in comments, you could consider dropping the *sunt*, since forms of the verb "to be" are often elided in Latin. This would give *Omnia ut oportet*. This version (literally "All things as they ought to be") is somewhat ambiguous as it could describe an actual state of affairs or some general aspiration; on the other hand, it's certainly more pithy, so the choice is up to you.

Comment: This is a great option! Would it be possible to drop the *sunt* if it's used as a motto?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I think so, but it might be a little ambiguous. Editing to mention that possibility.