# How to say “dudes rock” in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

I want to translate "dudes rock" into Latin.
Google Translate and working with synonyms got me to *viri sunt prodigiosus* (“men are amazing” more or less?).
But I'm wondering if there’s an idiom or expression that would translate more felicitously.
“Men can be charming in their simplicity” (i.e. doing something possibly juvenile yet wholesome) is maybe close to the sense of the expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjective *prodigiosus* means "unnatural, strange, wonderful, marvellous, prodigious".
Not a perfect fit, but certainly an option if you like the tone.
If you want to use that, it should be in the plural form *prodigiosi* instead.
[Google Translate is horrible with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79) and is not to be trusted.

A nice simple option would be to say: ***Valent viri***, "men are strong".
While the literal meaning is different, I think that the Latin *valere* corresponds pretty well to the English "to rock" in this sense.

Something related that might be worth considering is the famous hexameter verse:

> *Sunt pueri pueri, pueri puerilia tractant.*
> Boys are boys, boys do boyish things.

This is a nice way to refer to juvenile behavior in men.
I think this works best with the word "boy" instead of "man", not only because that is the original phrasing.