# How much online translating website is reliable for translating latin to english?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I am a researcher who does not understand the Latin language. Sometimes I need to translate a full journal paper from Latin to the English language. I tried several websites such as [Google](https://translate.google.co.in/), [Bing](https://www.bing.com/translator), [Yandex](https://translate.yandex.com/), and Translateking to [translate Latin to English](https://translateking.com/translate/latin-to-english-translation). There are several drawbacks with these online translators such as we cannot translate the full documents or pdf files. Sometimes, it does the imperfect translation. Can somebody suggest a good tool to translate a full document with higher accuracy?

Comment: Unfortunately, a good tool doesn't exist. Check out our thread on [Google Translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/what-is-google-translate-good-for).

Comment: Just to have mentioned it: For Ancient Greek, there are (to the best of my knowledge) no tools at all.

Answer (score 3):

Let me write as an answer what was already given in the comment:
**There is no such tool.**

The automatic translation tools are very unreliable with Latin.
We have previously explored [the case of Google Translate with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), and no tool appears to do much better.

The conclusion is:
**If you need to understand a complicated document written in Latin, you need a person who understands Latin.**
That person can be you or someone else, but human work is needed, and the machine translation can well be completely useless to that human.
There is no shortcut.