# "Would you like to visit Paris?" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I teach myself Latin. What is the best translation of the sentence "Would you like to visit Paris?" into Latin? Suggestions:

1. Paris visitare vis? (Google Translate version)
2. Paridem visitare vis? (my translation, with accusative)

Thank you.

EDIT: 3) Lutetiam visitare vis?

Comment: You might want to check out how awful [Google Translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/what-is-google-translate-good-for).

Comment: #2 would involve a visit to a person named Paris, but I assume you mean the city?

Comment: I am asking one person if they would like to travel to a city called Paris.

Comment: Are the questions you're asking questions that you thought up yourself? Questions from Duolingo? Questions from a textbook? Your progress is going to be extremely slow if you have to depend on SE to check your sentences one at a time. You might want to get a textbook that includes answers.

Answer (score 4):

First, as I mentioned in the comment, Google Translate is not great. Don't expect to get grammatically correct sentences from it consistently. Case in point: it leaves *Paris* uninflected.

When you have a yes or no question, the enclitic *-ne* can be attached to the emphasized word (often the verb, but any important word can take it), which is then typically found at the beginning. So, *visne...* is how you could start off the sentence: "Do you want..."

The ancient city of Paris was called in Latin [*Lutetia*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DLutetia). The verb *visitare* will take an accusative as an object, so *Lutetiam visitare* is grammatically correct. As cnread points out, *Paris* is the name of the son of Priam and Hecuba, that enemy of Menelaus who left back to Troy with Helen. If you're visiting him, it would be *Paridem*.

cnread points out one more thing: for a place, the better verb to use is [*visere*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dviso) (alternative, [*invisere*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dinviso) is a good choice, too).

Comment: I'm not sure visitare is the correct verb, at least if the target of the textbook that's being used is classical Latin (and indeed a sentence that talks about visiting Paris suggests a more modern, conversational target). According to OLD, although it can mean simply 'to visit' when the object is a person, it's otherwise a true frequentative, meaning 'to see frequently or habitually.' For just an isolated visit to a place, it appears to me that the verb should be visere instead.

Comment: @cnread Huh, I didn't see that in L&S. For sure *visere* (or even *invisere*) is the better verb. I'll have to see if anyone slipped and used it with a place, but it does strike me odd that it would be OK-ish with a person and incorrect with a place.