# Is this Latin translation of "I see the world" correct?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I used Google Translate to translate "I see the world" to Latin. Google gave me "I videre mundum." Is this correct? If not, what would be correct and what did Google actually give me?

Comment: Google Translate gave you gibberish. It is very bad for Latin, and here it does not produce a grammatical complete sentence. **videre** is the present active infinitive of [video](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/video#Latin), so, literally, "to see." **mundum** is the accusative singular of [mundus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mundus#Latin), in this context "world; universe." These words are not combined in a way that would make sense as a sentence; you'd have to conjugate the verb for it to do so.

Comment: `*I` at the front is not Latin at all, if it is supposed to be a word; the machine seems to be either (a) mistakenly treating it as an untranslated proper name, or possibly (b) mistakenly treating it as the Roman *numeral* I, i.e., 1 -- for reasons that I'm sure make sense inside a patchy computer model but don't make sense to me. Latin for "I," the speaker (1st person pronoun in nominative singular), is [ego](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ego#Latin), but you usually wouldn't use this pronoun explicitly in a sentence if it is clear from the conjugation of the verb.

Comment: When I put "I see the world into Google Translate, I get "video mundum," which is a valid response, but not the most typical order of the words used in Classical Latin.

Answer (score 10):

[As usual with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), Google gave you nonsense.
It's not even wholly in Latin, so translating is pointless.

The simplest valid translation is ***mundum video***.
Whether that's the right choice for you depends on the context, but it's a pretty safe bet.
You can edit your question to add details about the use context you had in mind.

Answer (score 5):

The word mundus has lots of different meanings, including “ornament”, “clean”, “the cosmos, the universe”. If you are talking about the planet earth it would be less ambiguous to use orbis terrarum, in your case orbem terrarum video.