# "One of a kind" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I want to get "one of a kind" tattooed on me in Latin, but I can't seem to find a translation that makes sense with the context. I want it to mean I am one of a kind but it is translating it out of context into the wrong parts of speech. For example, I have gotten "in genere suo" which when I flip it back translates to "in their family" or "Unum genus" which translates to "one gender."

Answer (score 7):

There is a standard phrase that means exactly what you want:

> suī generis

literally, "of its/his/her own kind". The phrase is common even in English. You can see a sampling of its usage [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sui+generis%22&tbas=0&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsbCOz2Yv6-1GRaVDKhMJh-d28whaQ:1658516137985&source=lnt&tbs=bkv:f&sa=X&biw=1089&bih=992&dpr=1.5).

P.S. Never trust [Google Translate for Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/118).

Comment: You don't even need to point out Google Books, since sui generis [has its own Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sui_generis).

Comment: Yes, although I think it's rare to use *suus* for yourself. Perhaps [*mei*] *proprii generis*?

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Hmm, good point. That might make a good competing answer. _Sui generis_ has the advantage that English speakers will recognize it, but it might be inferior Latin. _In alia manu (manu nostri),_ maybe the third person makes sense here, as if one has been stamped (by the tattooist?) with the label "of her own kind".

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel [Turbae rettulī](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/18562/118).

Comment: @BenKovitz what would "of her own kind" in latin be?

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I would have understood it as "[hoc corpus] sui generis" *vel sim*.

Comment: @julia *sui generis* is the right one for "of her own kind." The Latin reflexive pronoun *sui* doesn't change for a male or female antecedent.

Comment: @julia As cmw said, _sui_ is the same for male, female, and neuter. The literal meaning of _sui generis_ is "of its/his/her own kind", but it's the idiomatic way in Latin to say "one of a kind", "in a class of her own", "unlike any other".

Answer (score 1):

This, rarely, could be a one-word answer, adjective: unus-a-um = "a single"; "sole"; "one and the same"; "the one and only". Alternatively, expanding: in unum = "so as to form a single mass"; ad unum = "to a man"; "without exception". (Oxford)

EDIT 23/7/2022:

Thanks to Sebastian for his timely intervention and the mentioning of "unicus".

The Wiki entry on "unicus" offers the following example:

> "quod petis, Oleniis inquam 'mihi missus ab arvis flos dabit: est hortis unicus ille meis.'" (Ovid Fasti 5. 251-2)

> "What you seek", I say, "a flower sent to me from the Olenian fields will provide: the only one [of its kind] is in my gardens."

Adapting:

> "unica in terra" = "the only one [of its kind] in the world"

Comment: Then the OP would have to get a tattoo saying simply *una*, but would anybody really translate that back as "one of a kind"? Similarly, I was thinking of suggesting *unicus/unica*, but I feel that it would sound unnatural without modifying a noun (e.g. *unica indole* or what have you).

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: How many translations have you seen that massage meanings way beyond their dictionary-definitions? The Oxford-things here are a reasonable fit; "ad unum" being the most appropriate, I think.

Comment: @tony I think not: "a. Ad unum, all together, unanimously, to a man, without exception:" It means "each and every one", not "unique."

Comment: @cmw: Yes, of course "ad unum" = "without exception". This was in my original answer--a close fit to the OP's request. It was Seb who introduced, "unicus/a". He declined to post this as an answer. Finding an application of "unicus" in a quote from Ovid, the EDIT provides an improvement.