# How would you say, they left/abandoned you but we remain/stay faithful

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, motto

Google translate gave me “relinquentes autem fideles permanemus” for “they left you but we remain faithful”but I know google translate can be just a tad less than accurate haha. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Tad less than accurate" is [understating it](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/what-is-google-translate-good-for) a tad bit. ;)

Comment: I see what you did there lol :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite literally:

**Illi te reliquerunt, nos autem fideles manemus.**

You can't use *relinquentes*, since it's a participle. The sentence you have now is "but leaving behind, we remain thoroughly loyal." The subject would be both doing the abandoning and the remaining. So you'll need to add a subject (I chose *illi*, "those people") and conjugate the verb appropriately.

While I chose *manemus*, you can still use *permanemus*, and there's nothing particularly wrong with it, but for some reason it's never recorded in the 1st person plural. But Livy has *fideliter permaneant*, so it's not a bad option.

Comment: I greatly appreciate it! I literally can’t say thank you enough!

Comment: There seems to be a contrast between "they" and "we" here, so you might add *Illi* at the beginning to capture that. (And I think *tibi* would normally be omitted as understood.)

Comment: @TKR Agreed on both counts. Changed.

Comment: @cmw: Where is Caesar using "tibi" insteasd of "in + acc."?