# "Habemus dicentis"?

Tags: translation-check

The headline on electoral-vote.com [this morning](https://www.electoral-vote.com/evp2023/Items/Jan07-1.html) is *Habemus Dicentis*, playing on *Habemus Papam* ("We have a pope") to announce the selection of Kevin McCarthy as Speaker of the U.S. House of Representives.

I would have expected a noun in the accusative case, like *Habemus Oratorem.* Is there really Latin precedent for *dicens* ("saying") meaning the speaker of a parliamentary body and/or putting a word in the genitive case with *habere* to indicate what we have?

Bonus question: If *dicens* is wrong, what *is* the Latin for the speaker of a legislative body?

Comment: Are you sure it's meant to be singular? *Dicentis* is a valid alternative for the plural accusative, if that makes any sense in the context.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Definitely singular: it refers to [Kevin McCarthy](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-64193932), elected after many rounds of voting, as often happens when Cardinals choose a Pope.

Comment: Seems a few people are running with the joke, but whoever came up with it should really be educated about how piss poor Google translate functions.

Comment: *Habemus dicentem*: "Hey, we have someone here who can actually talk!"

Answer (score 9):

As of today (2023-01-07), "habemus dicentis" is the translation provided by Google Translate when you type in the phrase ["we have a speaker"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22we+have+a+speaker%22+in+latin). Curiously, if you type in ["We have a speaker"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22We+have+a+speaker%22+in+latin) (capital "W"), you get something closer to your suggestion: "Habemus orator."

As anyone with [any experience with Latin Google Translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/what-is-google-translate-good-for) shouldn't be surprised to hear, neither translation is correct. "Habemus" requires the accusative. *Orator* is nominative and doesn't fit at all. As for the first, even the most generous interpretation--which parses *dicentis* as an accusative plural--yields, "We have [people who are] speaking." I'm not aware of any context in which the participle *dicens* has the same meaning as the political function of a "speaker," and (more obviously) there is only one. It seems pretty clear that someone without any knowledge of Latin plugged this into Google Translate and made it a headline.

My suggestion would be to use [*praeses*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpraeses), which is used [even in modern contexts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praeses) to refer to the presiding officer of a committee. The phrase would thus be:

> **Habemus praesidem.**

The one downside I see is that *praeses* is also a plausible translation for a "president." According to a comment from Joonas, though, some neo-Latin speakers distinguish *praeses* (head of a committee) from *praesidens* (head of state).

Comment: The Finnish *Nuntii Latini* had the convention that the chairman of any committee or similar is *praeses* and the president as the head of a republic is *praesidens*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I'll update--that removes the ambiguity!

Comment: And if you end the English sentence with a full stop, you get the perfectly grammatical *Oratorem habemus.* Google Translate is curiously sensitive to capitalization and interpunction.