# words meaning girl

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

On Google translate, I saw so many words which mean girl. Could you tell me the difference and relation between these words?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a dictionary like [Lewis and Short](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l) instead of Google Translate? Google Translate is [not good](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/what-is-google-translate-good-for).

Comment: @cmw I'm not professional enough to use a Latin dictionary.

Comment: @zzzgoo I disagree! They don't require you to know any Latin. We have a [long list of online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79), and trying out a couple of them should lead you to a tool that you're comfortable using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. Please first note that your primary source should be a Latin dictionary. As a French guy I use [Le Gaffiot](https://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php), but of course there are others.

Some of the words you mention are very rare, such as *pusa*. Likewise, *puera*, although possibly a historical derivate, is definitely not the dominating form. *Puella* is the correct feminine form of *puer* and means "young girl". This is the word you want to use in the general case.

*Juvenca* and *juvencula* on the one hand, *femina* and *femella* on the other hand, seem more informal, as they are not reserved to human girls or women but may apply to animals such as cows. The notion of *youth* is only present in the first pair through the root *juv-*.

*Virgo* on the contrary, applies to a young virgin and may convey the idea of  *unsoiled*, *immaculate*, the notion of *purity*, especially when referring to vestals.

*Pupa* and *pupilla*, for their part, both specifically refer to a little girl, a child.

The diminutive forms generally add an affectionate connotation.

My answer should be completed with genuine quotes but here you still get an overview, which is a better start than *Google Translate*.