# Translating English Quote "The most important conversation(s) you'll ever have are the ones you’ll have with yourself."

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I need help translating this quote into Latin, as I need it for a tattoo similar to the one in the photo. Same placement and I need the quote to be in 3 lines.

"The most important conversation(s) you'll ever have are the ones you’ll have with yourself."

I am not sure how to write it correctly in Latin or if the word "conversation" should be with an "S" and the end or without.

Google Translate says either one of these when I add/remove the "S" in "conversation"

"Colloquia gravissima semper habebis sunt quos apud te habebis."

or

"Maximi colloquii eris semper hi sunt quos apud te habebis."

[image]

Comment: A quick pointer: [Google Translate is horribly unreliable with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), and the two translations you mention are along the usual lines of gibberish.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta okay thanks, that’s what I thought too. Can you help me do the proper translation?