# Vita Bene Vixit in a commemorative magazine

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

Hi  I want to use the phrase   Vita Bene Vixit  in a commemorative magazine. google translation says 'Life Well Lived' Is this right? What exactly is the meaning of this phrase please. thanks

Comment: The literal meaning of this phrase is what Google Translate gave you, but it does not make sense to me. Where does this Latin phrase come from?

Comment: my father in law who turns 100 is a lover of latin phrases . So we were looking for a phrase signifying a life well spent or lived.  to be included in a magazine published to mark the occasion. so we google translated it.  Is it incorrect to use it  ? Or Do you know of  any other phrases which can be used in this instance ? much appreciated. many thanks

Comment: You might want to read this about Google Translate: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4353/78

Answer (score 8):

Verbatim, *vita bene victa* 'a life well lived'.

Some possible issues:

- *Victa* can mean either 'lived' or 'conquered'. That said, it seems to me that context makes it obvious which is intended. The so-called cognate accusative, where a verb which usually takes no object takes one that it etymologically related (*to live a life, to die a death,* etc.), is common enough in Latin that the intended meaning is likely to be assumed.
- *Victa* assumes that the life *has already been* lived and is therefore no longer being lived. If the person in question is still alive, then something like *vita quae bene vivitur* 'a life which is being well lived' would be more semantically appropriate, but less pithy. If this is the case, I would suggest adding more information about your intended meaning and application so that someone can come up with a more authentic Latin quotation.

By the by, to give a little more information about the issue that @cmw is tackling, some English verbs have only two so-called principal parts, whereas others have three:

|  | Strong Verb | Weak Verb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Drive | Live |
| 2. | Drove | Lived |
| 3. | Driven | Lived |

Your quotation is using the second *lived* (equivalent to *driven, victa*), but your translation is using the first *lived* (equivalent to *drove, vixit*). *Vita bene vixit* means that it is the life that has lived well rather than the person living.

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Note the vowel quantity differs between *vīcta* (from *vīvō*, "I live") and *victa* (from *vincō*, "I conquer)

Comment: great explanation. many thanks

Comment: we want to add a caption to the magazine we are going to publish to mark my father in law's 100 birthday ma. He loves Latin phrases  If so, can we use 'vita quae bene vivitur ' What do you mean by  'vita bene consumpta '  . many thanks for your suggestion

Comment: "Victa assumes that the life has already been lived and is therefore no longer being lived" -- how so? See @cnread's Cicero example for *vita bene acta*, where the context implies that the person not only is alive, but happy in the knowledge of a life well lived. At 100, it is probably safe to say most people will not resent the notion of drawing a certain bottom line already.

Comment: @lukman *Consumpta* is also fine, although personally I'd avoid it in an English speaking seeing, because I think that the English idea of "consume," i.e., to use up something, would interfere; plus of course the unpleasant association of *consumption*.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel But that's *acta*, not *victa*. Re: *consumpta*, perhaps they're [Callatians](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:tlg,0016,001:3:38)?

Comment: Quae mutatio morum apud Indos! Well, I recommend *acta* then to be on the safe side, although it is not clear to me that *vivere* should take on such a final meaning in the perfect. Although I do recall (as you do no doubt as well) a certain famous use of the perfect of *vivere* with a decidedly final meaning...

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Your point is valid. The perfect by definition has a sense of completion and, by extension, of finality, but this extension is not always and everywhere. I still advise against _victa,_ however, if only because the perfect of _vivere_ is a common euphemism for having died.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit tricky to get this succinctly in English, but it essentially means "a/the life is dead (but when it was alive, it had lived well." You can see this doesn't make any sense. The verb *vivere* in the past tense can mean "he/she/it has lived," with the idea that, since they're not longer living, they're dead.

I *think* you're trying to say "a life lived well." But the online translator mistakes the two forms of "lived" in English, one being a participle and the other a finite verb. *Vixit* is the latter. If you substituted out *vita* for *vir* ("man"), you will see the distinction immediately: "The man lived well."

If I am right, then I strongly do not recommend using this phrase, and opt for real Latin, in which case you have to think about what you intend to *mean*. For example, are you referring to living a good life? Then you could use *vita bona* ("the good life") or something like *vitam fortunatam vixit* ("he lived a fortunate life"). Or are you referring to a moral life? This too would be translated differently.

Eschewing the "word for word" approach and finding an authentic Latin turn of phrase will yield a better motto for your magazine. But before you can do that, you have to start with what you want the words to mean.

Comment: many thanks .appreciated

Answer (score 4):

In *De senectute* (*On old age*) §9, Cicero says:

> *...conscientia **bene actae vitae** multorumque bene factorum recordatio iucundissima est.*
>
> ...the consciousness of **a life well lived** and the recollection of many deeds well done are most pleasant.

This would give, in the nominative, **bene acta vita** or **vita bene acta**.

Comment: This is the best answer IMHO. My first idea was *... peracta*, and I found a few Neo-Latin examples for that, but the Cicero example is perfect.

Comment: Many thanks . We have decided to use vita bene acta.. It is really appreciated

Comment: This is a good answer. It also implies both _activity_ and _agency_ in the living of said life, rather than the simple living of it; that is, a life lived deliberately. @lukman , if you've decided on this answer, you might consider formally 'accepting' it, so that the user can receive internet points and the question can be marked as answered.